# How to convert SQLAlchemy row object to a Python dict?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there a simple way to iterate over column name and value pairs?

My version of SQLAlchemy is 0.5.6

Here is the sample code where I tried using `dict(row)`:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

print "sqlalchemy version:",sqlalchemy.__version__ 

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()
users_table = Table('users', metadata,
     Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
     Column('name', String),
)
metadata.create_all(engine) 

class User(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

user1 = User("anurag")
session.add(user1)
session.commit()

# uncommenting next line throws exception 'TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable'
#print dict(user1)
# this one also throws 'TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable'
for u in session.query(User).all():
    print dict(u)
```

Running this code on my system outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 37, in <module>
    print dict(u)
TypeError: 'User' object is not iterable
```

Comment: The title of the question does not match the question itself. According to [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=keyedtuple#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) *Result rows returned by Query that contain multiple ORM entities and/or column expressions make use of this class to return rows.* where *this class* is `sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple` which is *row object* from the question's title. However query in the question uses model (mapped) class thus the type of *row object* is the model class instead of `sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple`.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Question is from 2009 and mentions sqlalchemy version 0.5.6

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I couldn't get a good answer so I use this:

```
def row2dict(row):
    d = {}
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
        d[column.name] = str(getattr(row, column.name))

    return d
```

Edit: if above function is too long and not suited for some tastes here is a one liner (python 2.7+)

```
row2dict = lambda r: {c.name: str(getattr(r, c.name)) for c in r.__table__.columns}
```

Comment: More succinctly, `return dict((col, getattr(row, col)) for col in row.__table__.columns.keys())`.

Comment: @argentpepper yeah you may even do `row2dict = lambda row: dict((col, getattr(row, col)) for col in row.__table__.columns.keys())` to make it a real one liner, but I prefer my code to be readable, horizontally short, vertically long

Comment: What if my Column isn't assigned to an attribute of the same name?  IE, `x = Column('y', Integer, primary_key=True)` ?  None of these solutions work in this case.

Comment: Warning: `__table__.columns.keys()` won't work, because `columns` dictionary keys are not always strings (as `getattr` requires), but possibly all sorts of objects like `sqlalchemy.sql.expression._truncated_label`. Using `c.name` instead of `c` works for me.

Comment: drdaeman is right, here is the correct snippet: `return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}`

Comment: `row2dict()` will leave out columns defined with a `@hybrid_property`.  If you are using `@hybrid_property` to define columns you can use `for column in dir(row)` and exclude names starting with `_` or `__`.

Comment: This answer makes an invalid assumption: column names don't necessarily match attribute names.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me better than the other solution I did remove the cast to sting though it was throwing errors.

Comment: @RazerM's answer is much more correct because it returns the values as *objects* in the correct *type* (integer, decimals, datetimes, strings, null, etc.) whereas this answer returns the values as *strings*.

Comment: this is cool I change to use this form def row2dict(row):
    d = {}
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
        d[str(column.name).replace(str(row.__table__), "").lower()] = \
            getattr(row, str(column.name).replace(str(row.__table__) + ".", "").lower())

    return d

Comment: `{c.expression.name: getattr(obj, c.key) for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}` seems betters, because it make the dict key as database column name. For case when the model key is not equils the database column name.

Comment: newer sqlalchemy allows to just do `row.columns`

Answer (score 386):

You may access the internal `__dict__` of a SQLAlchemy object, like the following:

```
for u in session.query(User).all():
    print u.__dict__
```

Comment: Best answer in this thread, don't know why everyone else is proposing much more complicated solutions.

Comment: This gives an extra '_sa_instance_state' field, at least in version 0.7.9.

Comment: @LucianU what are the downsides of the extra `_sa_instance_state` field?

Comment: jberger, it's not a column name, so you have to remove it separately afterwards.

Comment: so this would be better: `dictret = dict(row.__dict__); dictret.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)`

Comment: this seems not ideal since as people have pointed out `__dict__` includes an `_sa_instance_state` entry which must then be removed. if you upgrade to a future version and other attributes are added you may have to go back and manually deal with them. if you want just column data (for example, to take a list of instances from a query and drop them in a pandas dataframe) then `{col.name: getattr(self, col.name) for col in self.__table__.columns}` as answered by Anurag Uniyal (with important corrections from comments to that answer) seems both more succinct and error-proof.

Comment: just another suggestion like lyfings' one: one can also use ```{k: v for k, v in item.__dict__.iteritems() if not str(k).startswith("_")}``` or even more specific as lyfing commented, not only with starting underscores. ( >= Python2.7, for Python3 use .items())

Comment: I'm guessing this is no longer supported as I get:  `AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '__dict__'`

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner The 2018-03-25 update is unclear - what does it "interprets it as a reference to a column/field" mean? and can you specify which version the behavior was changed? I'm getting "object is not iterable" for the current version of SQLAlchemy 1.2.6

Comment: @AdamTerrey in SQLAlchemy 1.2.5, the following works: `sel = self.table.select(); logs = sel.execute(); self.rows = [dict(r) for r in logs]` (semicolons are line breaks). The fields of rows `r` can be accessed via several methods (see the sample code block here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=execute#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy). By using `u.__dict__`, SQLAlchemy looks for a column called `__dict__`, if I'm reading the docs correctly.

Comment: yes, but `session.query(User).all()` doesn't return a ResultProxy of RowProxies in the same way as `session.execute(..)`- but just a simple list of instances of the `User` class. With regards to `__dict__` this is a magic python value representing all the attributes of any class instance. E.g. it is possible to do `class A(object): pass;  a = A(); a.__dict__['blah'] = 123; assert a.blah == 123`

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question even has `dict(u)` and correctly states that it throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: I've rolled back @ZuluDeltaNiner's edit since, as others noted here, it's wrong. The question (despite its misleading title) is asking how to get the values from an SQLAlchemy model instance as a dict, not the values from a `RowProxy`. Using `.__dict__` works for that, and `dict(...)` raises an error, even as of v1.2.14 (the latest stable release). The edit was wrong for the case being asked about, was kind of incoherent (I'm not sure what *either* of the "it"s in there were meant to refer to), and wrongly implied that some relevant behaviour has changed between 2012 and now.

Comment: There is certainly still room for improving the state of this question, though - the title and the use of the word "row" in the question lends itself to precisely @ZuluDeltaNiner's misinterpretation of the question, and could do with fixing. *Once* that's done, the previous 5 comments in this thread will be obsolete and able to be safely flagged for deletion (as will this one).

Comment: I just created a query which only consists of `func.<something>(...).label("something")` type columns. This returns a `collections.result` type object, which has no `__dict__` method (full list, surrounded by `__`: add, class, contains, delattr, doc, eq, format, ge, getattribute, getitem, getnewargs, getslice, gt, hash, init, iter, le, len, lt, module, mul, ne, new, reduce, reduce_ex, repr, rmul, setattr, sizeof, slots, str, subclasshook and _asdict, _fields, _real_fields, count).

Comment: @Gocht I think that this answer only applies to a query (with filter, etc.) from a session object, while `.execute()` from `create_engine` is different.

Comment: All of this is still insane. Why can't SQLAlchemy results just be serialized with jsonify?

Comment: You shouldn't try to access `__dict__` directly.

Comment: How would you implement this solution with [flask.json.jsonify()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify)?

Comment: I have been searching for a way to make a `dict` out of a model for *days*. This is the best answer, full stop. Still applicable in Jan 2021 with SQLAlchemy `1.3.x`

Comment: Note that even though it gives you a list of dicts, SqlAlchemy does a lot of extra work here: it constructs a lot of ORM objects that you don't really need. This is going to be *really slow* when objects are many.

Comment: In my case, SQLalchemy instance `u.__dict__` will NOT return content of any field unless you access the field explicitly in advance.

Comment: Not working with `collections.result` object :/

Comment: When I try this, I get `TypeError: Object of type InstanceState is not JSON serializable`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 244):

As per @zzzeek in comments:

> note that this is the correct answer for modern versions of
> SQLAlchemy, assuming "row" is a core row object, not an ORM-mapped
> instance.

```
for row in resultproxy:
    row_as_dict = row._mapping  # SQLAlchemy 1.4 and greater
    # row_as_dict = dict(row)  # SQLAlchemy 1.3 and earlier
```

background on `row._mapping`, new as of SQLAlchemy 1.4: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/stable/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Row._mapping

Comment: It says 'XXX object is not iterable', I am using 0.5.6, i get by session.query(Klass).filter().all()

Comment: @Anurag Uniyal:  Please update your question with (a) the smallest piece of code that shows the problem and (b) the real error traceback.  It's very hard to do this through comments and summaries of the code.

Comment: Please see the updated code, I am using same example given in the links you have mentioned, I also see no use of dict there?

Comment: note that this is the correct answer for modern versions of SQLAlchemy, assuming "row" is a core row object, not an ORM-mapped instance.

Comment: Also note that zzzeek is the creator of sqlalchemy.

Comment: Does anyone know why this works? RowProxy does not inherit from `collections.Mapping, dict, collections.OrderedDict() or collections.UserDict()`. And none of the descriptions I found for the `dict` constructor seem to fit.

Comment: Can anyone elaborate on this one? I'm a noob an don't get this.

Comment: @Joe you are right that it doesn't inherit from those types, but it does implement `__getitem__` and `keys` amongst other methods, so it quacks like a mapping. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/91739c774220e135019e4201b21173fcdc2c8c21/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L52

Comment: Yes, that's correct. https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-mapping

Comment: What is the difference between a core row object versus an ORM-mapped instance? This doesn't work for me on the rows from of `query(MyModel).all()`: *MyModel object is not iterable.*

Comment: I have tired to do this, but when you have many fields with the same name you will get strange results. for example when joining two tables in a raw query like "Select a.*, b.* from A a, B b"

Comment: This answer is unhelpful as you're not outlining how or what is "resultproxy"?

Comment: `resultproxy` is just a stand-in variable name (a proxy) for whatever _your_ results variable is. Replace it with your appropriate query results variable.

Comment: Note that `row._mapping` returns a [RowMapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowMapping) not a dict. You need to cast it to dict if you want to add keys or do other dict operations.

Comment: this should be marked as the correct answer given that we are in 2022, SQLAlchemy 1.4 is mature and soon we will have 2.0

Comment: @zzzeek Python convention is not to rely on "_anything" as its hands off. Why is this the correct thing to do in SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: The answer is good, but also for version 1.4 you need to use the suggested 1.3 approach, as per documentation is returns "RowMapping for this Row".

Comment: Others were asking how to get the "resultproxy". 
I used this kind of code: 
`resultproxy = session.get_bind().execute(text("select * from table")).all()`
  which returns a list of RowMapping object, which if you make them dict() are proper Python dictionaries. 
So, code like 
``` lang-js
all_dict_records = []
            for record in resultproxy:
                record_dict = dict(record._mapping)
                all_dict_records.append(record_dict)``` 
will get you a list of dictionaries from full result set. Then you can use json or process it..

Answer (score 124):

In SQLAlchemy v0.8 and newer, use the [inspection system](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html).

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def object_as_dict(obj):
    return {
        c.key: getattr(obj, c.key)
        for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs
    }

user = session.query(User).first()

d = object_as_dict(user)
```

Note that `.key` is the attribute name, which can be different from the column name, e.g. in the following case:

```
class_ = Column('class', Text)
```

This method also works for [`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property).

Comment: @DukeDougal I think this works from v0.8 (when the inspection system was added).

Comment: This doesn't take into account deferred columns

Comment: @Mark It's not clear to me that they should be excluded by default. Nevertheless, you can check that the keys aren't in `sqlalchemy.inspect(obj).unloaded`

Comment: While I won't use this for the results of query, inspect was very useful when using insert_many and I wanted to return the inserted entities (including any generated cols such as ids)

Comment: Good, but doesn't include attributes that are defined as relationships to other tables

Answer (score 70):

rows have an `_asdict()` function which gives a dict

```
In [8]: r1 = db.session.query(Topic.name).first()

In [9]: r1
Out[9]: (u'blah')

In [10]: r1.name
Out[10]: u'blah'

In [11]: r1._asdict()
Out[11]: {'name': u'blah'}
```

Comment: It is supposed to be private and not could possibly be removed/changed in future versions.

Comment: @balki It is [quite well documented](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) and as such not quite private. Though a leading underscore has that meaning in Python in general, here it is probably used in order to not clash with possible tuple keys.

Comment: This only works with KeyedTuple s, which are only returned when querying specific fields of a row. ie .query(Topic.name) returns a KeyedTuple, while .query(Topic) returns a Topic, which does not have ._asdict() - Derp. just saw STBs answer below.

Comment: `KeyedTuple` has been replaced with [`engine.Row`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=asdict#sqlalchemy.engine.Row._asdict) in [1.4](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html?highlight=keyedtuple#the-keyedtuple-object-returned-by-query-is-replaced-by-row)

Comment: `_asdict()` solved my problem

Answer (score 34):

Assuming the following functions will be added to the `class User` the following will return all key-value pairs of all columns:

```
def columns_to_dict(self):
    dict_ = {}
    for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
        dict_[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return dict_
```

unlike the other answers all but only those attributes of the object are returned which are [`Column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) attributes at class level of the object. Therefore no `_sa_instance_state` or any other attribute *SQLalchemy* or you add to the object are included. [Reference](http://piotr.banaszkiewicz.org/blog/2012/06/30/serialize-sqlalchemy-results-into-json/)

EDIT: Forget to say, that this also works on inherited Columns.

#### `hybrid_property` extention

If you also want to include `hybrid_property` attributes the following will work:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

def publics_to_dict(self) -> {}:
    dict_ = {}
    for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
        if not key.startswith('_'):
            dict_[key] = getattr(self, key)

    for key, prop in inspect(self.__class__).all_orm_descriptors.items():
        if isinstance(prop, hybrid_property):
            dict_[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return dict_
```

I assume here that you mark Columns with an beginning `_` to indicate that you want to hide them, either because you access the attribute by an `hybrid_property` or you simply do not want to show them. [Reference](http://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/orm.html#get_hybrid_properties)

*Tipp* `all_orm_descriptors` also returns [hybrid_method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method) and [AssociationProxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy.AssociationProxy) if you also want to include them.

#### Remarks to other answers

Every answer (like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10370224/3644818), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237320/3644818) )  which based on the `__dict__` attribute simply returns all attributes of the object. This could be much more attributes then you want. Like I sad this includes `_sa_instance_state` or any other attribute you define on this object.

Every answer (like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960571/3644818), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958228/3644818) ) which is based on the `dict()` function only works on *SQLalchemy* row objects returned by `session.execute()` not on the classes you define to work with, like the `class User` from the question.

The [solving answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960546/3644818) which is based on `row.__table__.columns` will definitely **not** work. `row.__table__.columns` contains the column names of the SQL Database. These *can only* be equal to the attributes name of the python object. If not you get an `AttributeError`.
For answers (like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454618/3644818), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3355665/3644818) ) based on `class_mapper(obj.__class__).mapped_table.c` it is the same.

Comment: Perfect for adding a simple method to make models easily JSON serializable

Answer (score 32):

as @balki mentioned:

The `_asdict()` method can be used if you're querying a specific field because it is returned as a [KeyedTuple](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple).

```
In [1]: foo = db.session.query(Topic.name).first()
In [2]: foo._asdict()
Out[2]: {'name': u'blah'}
```

Whereas, if you do not specify a column you can use one of the other proposed methods - such as the one provided by @charlax. Note that this method is only valid for 2.7+.

```
In [1]: foo = db.session.query(Topic).first()
In [2]: {x.name: getattr(foo, x.name) for x in foo.__table__.columns}
Out[2]: {'name': u'blah'}
```

Comment: If the python ORM class attributes have different names from the database columns, try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947294/when-the-sqlalchemy-orm-class-attributes-are-different-from-database-columns-ho

Comment: actually, a better solution for all cases is provided by the sqlalchemy author at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27948279/1023033

Comment: When I try this I get ResultProxy object has no attribute '_asdict'

Comment: @slashdottir, are you executing your query object (calling the `.first()` method)?

Comment: This answer makes an invalid assumption: column names don't necessarily match attribute names – see RazerM's answer.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost

Comment: True! However I've found this to be more useful in my experiences.

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but since this the first result for "sqlalchemy row to dict" in Google it deserves a better answer.

The RowProxy object that SqlAlchemy returns has the items() method:
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy.items

It simply returns a list of (key, value) tuples. So one can convert a row to dict using the following:

In Python <= 2.6:

```
rows = conn.execute(query)
list_of_dicts = [dict((key, value) for key, value in row.items()) for row in rows]
```

In Python >= 2.7:

```
rows = conn.execute(query)
list_of_dicts = [{key: value for (key, value) in row.items()} for row in rows]
```

Comment: You can just do `list_of_dicts = [dict(row.items()) for row in rows]`

Comment: One snag is that the column names that SQLAlchemy uses in a result set are `table_name_column_name`, if you want different names (eg. just `column_name`), use the `.label` method. `session.query(
            MyTable.column_name.label('column_name'), ... )`

Comment: Hi I am getting this issue pls help me

* datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 24, 18, 52, 50) is not JSON serializable *

Comment: It seems that `Row.items()` disappeared in SQLAlchemy 1.4. If you were using it in SQLAlchemy 1.3, you will need to change to `dict(row).items()`

Answer (score 20):

A very simple solution is `row._asdict()`:

```py
data = session.query(Table).all()
[row._asdict() for row in data]
```

References:

- [`sqlalchemy.engine.Row._asdict()` (v1.4)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=asdict#sqlalchemy.engine.Row._asdict)
- [`sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict()` (v1.3)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=dict#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict)

Comment: At this moment it is not in the docs. Maybe it is deprecated.

Comment: I've added links to the 1.4 and 1.3 docs.

Comment: Confirm this works in 1.4. This should be the accepted answer IMHO

Comment: Important: the `Table` mentioned here is not a `Model` (a class), but rather a `Table` instance (that can be accessed as `Model.__table__`. The model (the most common way of declaring tables) does not have this attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this note @lowercase00 so in the example above the query would then be: `data = session.query(Model.__table__).all()` and then each instance will have the `_asdict` attribute

Answer (score 20):

with sqlalchemy 1.4

```
session.execute(select(User.id, User.username)).mappings().all()
>> [{'id': 1, 'username': 'Bob'}, {'id': 2, 'username': 'Alice'}]
```

Comment: fyi for the unwary: you need to use select 2.0 query rather than session.query (at least for my use case), or this still not work.

Comment: this works great if you're selecting specific columns. if you run something like `session.execute(select(User)).mappings().all()` to select the whole object you get this result: `[{'User': User(id=1, username='Bob')}, {'User': User(id=2, username='Alice')}]`

Comment: however you can do `session.execute(select('*').select_from(User)).mappings().all()` and it will give you `[{'id': 1, 'username': 'Bob'}, {'id': 2, 'username': 'Alice'}]`. or if you filter the results, for example: `session.execute(select('*').filter(User.id.in_([1, 2]))).mappings().all()`, should get you the same result. just need a way to specify which table you're selecting '*' from.

Comment: This only works if you select specific columns.

Answer (score 14):

Following @balki answer, **since SQLAlchemy 0.8** you can use `_asdict()`, available for `KeyedTuple` objects. This renders a pretty straightforward answer to the original question. Just, change in your example the last two lines (the for loop) for this one:

```
for u in session.query(User).all():
   print u._asdict()
```

This works because in the above code `u` is an object of type class [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple), since `.all()` returns a list of `KeyedTuple`. Therefore it has the method [`_asdict()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict), which nicely returns u as a dictionary.

WRT the answer by @STB: AFAIK, anything that `.all()` returns is a list of `KeypedTuple`. Therefore, the above works either if you specify a column or not, as long as you are dealing with the result of `.all()` as applied to a `Query` object.

Comment: This may have been true in the past, but on SQLAlchemy v1.0 `.all()` returns a list of `User` instances, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @RazerM, sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. The for loop should precisely loop through the list of User instances, converting them (u) to dictionaries, and then printing them...

Comment: `User` instances don't have an `_asdict` method. See https://gist.github.com/RazerM/2eff51571b3c70e8aeecd303c2a2bc8d

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks. Instead of KeyedTuple, now .all() returns User objects. So the problem for v1.0 (and up, I assume) is how to get a dictionary out of a User object. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 12):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper

def asdict(obj):
    return dict((col.name, getattr(obj, col.name))
                for col in class_mapper(obj.__class__).mapped_table.c)
```

Comment: Be aware of the difference between local_table and mapped_table. For example, if you apply some sort of table inheritance in your db (tbl_employees > tbl_managers, tbl_employees > tbl_staff), your mapped classes will need to reflect this (Manager(Employee), Staff(Employee)). mapped_table.c will give you the column names of both the base table and the inheriting table. local_table only gives you the name of your (inheriting) table.

Comment: This avoids giving the  '_sa_instance_state' field, at least in version 0.8+.

Comment: This answer makes an invalid assumption: column names don't necessarily match attribute names.

Answer (score 12):

Refer to [Alex Brasetvik's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958228/4645639), you can use one line of code to solve the problem

```
row_as_dict = [dict(row) for row in resultproxy]
```

Under the comment section of Alex Brasetvik's Answer, zzzeek the creator of SQLAlchemy stated this is the "Correct Method" for the problem.

Comment: @Greenonline Sure, the approval comment is under the Alex Brasetvik's answer. Edited to added link to his answer

Comment: What is the `resultproxy` ?

Answer (score 11):

With python 3.8+, we can do this with dataclass, and the `asdict` method that comes with it:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)


@dataclass
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.email = 'hello@example.com'


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = SessionMaker()

user1 = User("anurag")
session.add(user1)
session.commit()

query_result = session.query(User).one()  # type: User
print(f'{query_result.id=:}, {query_result.name=:}, {query_result.email=:}')
# query_result.id=1, query_result.name=anurag, query_result.email=hello@example.com

query_result_dict = asdict(query_result)
print(query_result_dict)
# {'id': 1, 'name': 'anurag'}
```

The key is to use the `@dataclass` decorator, and annotate each column with its type (the `: str` part of the `name: str = Column(String)` line).

Also note that since the `email` is not annotated, it is not included in `query_result_dict`.

Comment: On Python3.7 I get "NameError: name 'asdict' is not defined"

Comment: My bad! It's a function added in python 3.8. Fixed my answer.

Comment: So pythonic. 3.8 is awesome. But you don't really need the __init__ method do you? declarative and dataclass both provide generic init methods.

Comment: @JeffLaughlin It's not needed, but I was just being loyal to OP's code, and also wanted to provide a way to add default value to `email` field.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way to use dataclasses with sqlalchemy. See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html#orm-declarative-native-dataclasses But using `dataclasses.asdict` is indeed the best way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

I've found this post because I was looking for a way to convert a SQLAlchemy row into a dict. I'm using SqlSoup... but the answer was built by myself, so, if it could helps someone here's my two cents:

```
a = db.execute('select * from acquisizioni_motes')
b = a.fetchall()
c = b[0]

# and now, finally...
dict(zip(c.keys(), c.values()))
```

Comment: or, if you prefer..:    [ dict(zip(i.keys(), i.values())) for i in b ]

Comment: This is the only syntax I've found that actually works!  I've been trying stuff for over an hour.

Comment: For core selects, the `RowProxy` (`c` in this answer) adheres to the mapping protocol, so you can just call `dict(c)`.

Answer (score 9):

You could try to do it in this way.

```
for u in session.query(User).all():
    print(u._asdict())
```

It use a built-in method in the query object that return a dictonary object of the query object.

references: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

Comment: Add some more explaining maybe?

Comment: Nothing really more to explain. It's a built-in method on the result object. So whether you do this for all results, or a single row, there is a built-in `_asdict()` method that essentially zips the field names with field values and returns the result as a dictionary.

Comment: Very concise and I wish it worked but `u` in my case is a string, and I get error ``Model' object has no attribute '_asdict'` @hllau below worked for me

Answer (score 8):

The expression you are iterating through evaluates to list of model *objects*, not rows. So the following is correct usage of them:

```
for u in session.query(User).all():
    print u.id, u.name
```

Do you realy need to convert them to dicts? Sure, there is a lot of ways, but then you don't need ORM part of SQLAlchemy:

```
result = session.execute(User.__table__.select())
for row in result:
    print dict(row)
```

**Update**: Take a look at `sqlalchemy.orm.attributes` module. It has a set of functions to work with object state, that might be useful for you, especially `instance_dict()`.

Comment: I want to convert them to dict to, because some other code needs data as dict, and i want a generic way because I will not know what columns a model object have

Comment: and when I get handle to them I have access to model objects only so i can't use session.execute etc

Answer (score 6):

I've just been dealing with this issue for a few minutes.
The answer marked as correct doesn't respect the type of the fields.
Solution comes from dictalchemy adding some interesting fetures.
https://pythonhosted.org/dictalchemy/
I've just tested it and works fine.

```
Base = declarative_base(cls=DictableModel)

session.query(User).asdict()
{'id': 1, 'username': 'Gerald'}

session.query(User).asdict(exclude=['id'])
{'username': 'Gerald'}
```

Comment: This should be the new best sollution. How lucky that I checked every answer found this one! No more '_sa_instance_state' to be delt with.

Answer (score 5):

```
class User(object):
    def to_dict(self):
        return dict([(k, getattr(self, k)) for k in self.__dict__.keys() if not k.startswith("_")])
```

That should work.

Comment: what happens if column name starts with "_" ?

Comment: I would imagine that you really shouldn't name your columns with a leading underscore. If you do, it won't work.

If it's just the odd one, that you know about, you could modify it to add those columns.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert sqlalchemy object to dictionary like this and return it as json/dictionary.

Helper functions:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


def asdict(self):
    result = OrderedDict()
    for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
        if getattr(self, key) is not None:
            result[key] = str(getattr(self, key))
        else:
            result[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return result


def to_array(all_vendors):
    v = [ ven.asdict() for ven in all_vendors ]
    return json.dumps(v)
```

Driver Function:

```
def all_products():
    all_products = Products.query.all()
    return to_array(all_products)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

1.

```
for row in session.execute(session.query(User).statement):
    print(dict(row))
```

2.

```
selected_columns = User.__table__.columns
rows = session.query(User).with_entities(*selected_columns).all()
for row in rows :
    print(row._asdict())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how Elixir does it. The value of this solution is that it allows recursively including the dictionary representation of relations.

```python
def to_dict(self, deep={}, exclude=[]):
    """Generate a JSON-style nested dict/list structure from an object."""
    col_prop_names = [p.key for p in self.mapper.iterate_properties \
                                  if isinstance(p, ColumnProperty)]
    data = dict([(name, getattr(self, name))
                 for name in col_prop_names if name not in exclude])
    for rname, rdeep in deep.iteritems():
        dbdata = getattr(self, rname)
        #FIXME: use attribute names (ie coltoprop) instead of column names
        fks = self.mapper.get_property(rname).remote_side
        exclude = [c.name for c in fks]
        if dbdata is None:
            data[rname] = None
        elif isinstance(dbdata, list):
            data[rname] = [o.to_dict(rdeep, exclude) for o in dbdata]
        else:
            data[rname] = dbdata.to_dict(rdeep, exclude)
    return data
```

Comment: Link is dead. Next time please copy the relevant code here as well.

Comment: Will do next time. If I remember correctly, the function was quite long.

Answer (score 2):

**With this code you can also to add to your query "filter" or "join" and this work!**

```
query = session.query(User)
def query_to_dict(query):
        def _create_dict(r):
            return {c.get('name'): getattr(r, c.get('name')) for c in query.column_descriptions}

    return [_create_dict(r) for r in query]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of everyone and myself, here is how I use it:

```
def run_sql(conn_String):
  output_connection = engine.create_engine(conn_string, poolclass=NullPool).connect()
  rows = output_connection.execute('select * from db1.t1').fetchall()  
  return [dict(row) for row in rows]
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete @Anurag Uniyal 's answer, here is a method that will recursively follow relationships:

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

def to_dict(obj, with_relationships=True):
    d = {}
    for column in obj.__table__.columns:
        if with_relationships and len(column.foreign_keys) > 0:
             # Skip foreign keys
            continue
        d[column.name] = getattr(obj, column.name)

    if with_relationships:
        for relationship in inspect(type(obj)).relationships:
            val = getattr(obj, relationship.key)
            d[relationship.key] = to_dict(val) if val else None
    return d

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(TEXT)
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('addresses.id')
    address = relationship('Address')

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(TEXT)


user = User(first_name='Nathan', address=Address(city='Lyon'))
# Add and commit user to session to create ids

to_dict(user)
# {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Nathan', 'address': {'city': 'Lyon'}}
to_dict(user, with_relationship=False)
# {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'Nathan', 'address_id': 1}
```

Comment: in case the default for 'with_relationships' is changed to false, better pass this value through to the recursive call. ie:

`d[relationship.key] = to_dict(val,with_relationships) if val else None`

Comment: how can I achieve the result, if I want to join the user and address table based upon address_id column and fetch all the column from user table and only id column from address table.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from copy import copy

def to_record(row):
    record = copy(row.__dict__)
    del record["_sa_instance_state"]
    return record
```

If not using copy, you might run into errors.

Answer (score 2):

As OP stated, calling the dict initializer raises an exception with the message "User" object is not iterable. So the real question is how to make a SQLAlchemy Model iterable?

We'll have to implement the special methods `__iter__` and `__next__`, but if we inherit directly from the declarative_base model, we would still run into the undesirable "_sa_instance_state" key. What's worse, is we would have to loop through `__dict__.keys()` for every call to `__next__` because the `keys()` method returns a View -- an iterable that is not indexed. This would increase the time complexity by a factor of N, where N is the number of keys in `__dict__`. Generating the dict would cost O(N^2). We can do better.

We can implement our own Base class that implements the required special methods and stores a list of of the column names that can be accessed by index, reducing the time complexity of generating the dict to O(N). This has the added benefit that we can define the logic once and inherit from our Base class anytime we want our model class to be iterable.

```
class IterableBase(declarative_base()):
    __abstract__ = True

    def _init_keys(self):
        self._keys = [c.name for c in self.__table__.columns]
        self._dict = {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._init_keys()

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if name not in ('_dict', '_keys', '_n') and '_dict' in self.__dict__:
            self._dict[name] = value

    def __iter__(self):
        self._n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._n >= len(self._keys):
            raise StopIteration
        self._n += 1
        key = self._keys[self._n-1]
        return (key, self._dict[key])
```

Now the User class can inherit directly from our IterableBase class.

```
class User(IterableBase):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

You can confirm that calling the dict function with a User instance as an argument returns the desired dictionary, sans "_sa_instance_state". You may have noticed the `__setattr__` method that was declared in the IterableBase class. This ensures the _dict is updated when attributes are mutated or set after initialization.

```
def main():
    user1 = User('Bob')
    print(dict(user1))
    # outputs {'id': None, 'name': 'Bob'}
    user1.id = 42
    print(dict(user1))
    # outputs {'id': 42, 'name': 'Bob'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is the working version of April 2022. Using dictalchemy was my preferred method but it's unmaintained since 2015.

Answer (score 1):

I have a variation on Marco Mariani's answer, expressed as a decorator. The main difference is that it'll handle *lists* of entities, as well as safely ignoring some other types of return values (which is very useful when writing tests using mocks):

```
@decorator
def to_dict(f, *args, **kwargs):
  result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  if is_iterable(result) and not is_dict(result):
    return map(asdict, result)

  return asdict(result)

def asdict(obj):
  return dict((col.name, getattr(obj, col.name))
              for col in class_mapper(obj.__class__).mapped_table.c)

def is_dict(obj):
  return isinstance(obj, dict)

def is_iterable(obj):
  return True if getattr(obj, '__iter__', False) else False
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the contents of this :class:`.KeyedTuple` as a dictionary

```
In [46]: result = aggregate_events[0]

In [47]: type(result)
Out[47]: sqlalchemy.util._collections.result

In [48]: def to_dict(query_result=None):
    ...:     cover_dict = {key: getattr(query_result, key) for key in query_result.keys()}
    ...:     return cover_dict
    ...: 
    ...:     

In [49]: to_dict(result)
Out[49]: 
{'calculate_avg': None,
 'calculate_max': None,
 'calculate_min': None,
 'calculate_sum': None,
 'dataPointIntID': 6,
 'data_avg': 10.0,
 'data_max': 10.0,
 'data_min': 10.0,
 'data_sum': 60.0,
 'deviceID': u'asas',
 'productID': u'U7qUDa',
 'tenantID': u'CvdQcYzUM'}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can get a list of object in dict:

```
def queryset_to_dict(query_result):
   query_columns = query_result[0].keys()
   res = [list(ele) for ele in query_result]
   dict_list = [dict(zip(query_columns, l)) for l in res]
   return dict_list

query_result = db.session.query(LanguageMaster).all()
dictvalue=queryset_to_dict(query_result)
```

Answer (score 1):

An improved version of Anurag Uniyal's version, which takes into account types:

```
def sa_vars(row):
    return {
        column.name: column.type.python_type(getattr(row, column.name))
        for column in row.__table__.columns
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a newly minted Python programmer and ran into problems getting to JSON with Joined tables.  Using information from the answers here I built a function to return reasonable results to JSON where the table names are included avoiding having to alias, or have fields collide.

Simply pass the result of a session query:

test = Session().query(VMInfo, Customer).join(Customer).order_by(VMInfo.vm_name).limit(50).offset(10)

json = sqlAl2json(test)

```
def sqlAl2json(self, result):
    arr = []
    for rs in result.all():
        proc = []
        try:
            iterator = iter(rs)
        except TypeError:
            proc.append(rs)
        else:
            for t in rs:
                proc.append(t)

        dict = {}
        for p in proc:
            tname = type(p).__name__
            for d in dir(p):
                if d.startswith('_') | d.startswith('metadata'):
                    pass
                else:
                    key = '%s_%s' %(tname, d)
                    dict[key] = getattr(p, d)
        arr.append(dict)
    return json.dumps(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your models table column is not equie mysql column.

such as :

```
class People:
    id: int = Column(name='id', type_=Integer, primary_key=True)
    createdTime: datetime = Column(name='create_time', type_=TIMESTAMP,
                               nullable=False,
                               server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
                               default=func.now())
    modifiedTime: datetime = Column(name='modify_time', type_=TIMESTAMP,
                                server_default=text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"),
                                default=func.now())
```

Need to use:

```
 from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper 
 def asDict(self):
        return {x.key: getattr(self, x.key, None) for x in
            class_mapper(Application).iterate_properties}
```

if you use this way you can get modify_time and create_time both are None

```
{'id': 1, 'create_time': None, 'modify_time': None}


    def to_dict(self):
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name, None)
         for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

Because Class Attributes name not equal with column store in mysql

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_dict(row):
    return {column.name: getattr(row, row.__mapper__.get_property_by_column(column).key) for column in row.__table__.columns}


for u in session.query(User).all():
    print(to_dict(u))
```

This function might help. 
I can't find better solution to solve problem when attribute name is different then column names.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need it everywhere in your project, I apriciate @anurag answered it works fine. till this point I was using it, but it'll mess all your code and also wont work with entity change.

Rather try this,
inherit your base query class in SQLAlchemy

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, BaseQuery


class Query(BaseQuery):
    def as_dict(self):
        context = self._compile_context()
        context.statement.use_labels = False
        columns = [column.name for column in context.statement.columns]

        return list(map(lambda row: dict(zip(columns, row)), self.all()))


db = SQLAlchemy(query_class=Query)
```

after that wherever you'll define your object "as_dict" method will be there.

Answer (score 0):

use dict Comprehensions

```
for u in session.query(User).all():
    print ({column.name: str(getattr(row, column.name)) for column in row.__table__.columns})
```

Comment: Please refrain from code-only answers - Take the time to post a little explanation as to how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

After querying the database using following SQLAlchemy code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///./examples/sql_app.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
query = sqlalchemy.select(TABLE)
result = engine.execute(query).fetchall()
```

You can use this one-liner:

```
query_dict = [record._mapping for record in results]
```

Comment: This answer had been posted 13 years before yours.

Comment: @Eric woke up and chose violence lol

Answer (score 0):

`sqlalchemy-utils` has [get_columns](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orm_helpers.html#get-columns) to help with this.

You could write:

```py
{column: getattr(row, column) for column in get_columns(row)}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQlAlchemy 2.x supports [dataclasses](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html). Based on the example of the original [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html):

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import MappedAsDataclass


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    """subclasses will be converted to dataclasses"""


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
```

you can apply `dataclasses.asdict` to instances of `User`:

```py
import dataclasses

print(dataclasses.asdict(User(id=1,name='foo')))
# {'id': 1,'name': 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of SQL Alchemy 2.0 if you are using [declarative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/quickstart.html) you can use __dict__ directly on the query results.

```
        with Session() as session:
          statement = select(User).filter_by({"id": 1})
          result = session.scalars(statement).one()

          dict_result = result.__dict__
```

In latest versions of SQL Alchemy 2.0 with [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/) library
I think you can do like that:

```
        with Session() as session:
          statement = select(User).filter_by({"id": 1})
          result = session.scalars(statement).one()

          dict_result = result.model_dump()
```

Comment: I think `model_dump` is a pydantic feature, not SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Oh you're right! 
I was using an additional library on my example.
I updated my post accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Here is a super simple way of doing it

```
row2dict = lambda r: dict(r.items())
```

Answer (score -1):

In most scenarios, column name is fit for them. But maybe you write the code like follows:

```
class UserModel(BaseModel):
    user_id = Column("user_id", INT, primary_key=True)
    email = Column("user_email", STRING)
```

the column.name "user_email" while the field name is "email", the column.name could not work well as before.

[sqlalchemy_base_model.py](https://gist.github.com/kaka19ace/760380b8c267a3fc288c)

[also i write the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746136/how-to-get-column-and-values-dictionary-in-sqlalchemy-model/31330672#31330672)

Answer (score -1):

A solution that works with inherited classes too:

```
from itertools import chain
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()


class Mixin(object):
    def as_dict(self):
        tables = [base.__table__ for base in self.__class__.__bases__ if base not in [Base, Mixin]]
        tables.append(self.__table__)
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in chain.from_iterable([x.columns for x in tables])}
```

Comment: My answer using the inspection system already works for table inheritance without having to go through all that trouble

Comment: Yes but it actually works and answer the question, so why a downvote ?

Comment: You're also using the column name which can be different from the attribute name.

Comment: There could be other, *non declarative* bases without `__table__` attribute and this code does not account for such. That's what *inspect* module is for.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have much experience with this, but the following seems to work for what I'm doing:

```
dict(row)
```

This seems too simple (compared to the other answers here). What am I missing?

Comment: If you're claming that your simple answer works, you should provide evidence. I think you're using a core select; this question is about ORM queries.

Comment: Yes. I had not noticed this question is about ORM. I am using core.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to work with a RowProxy, and was frustrated by the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html?highlight=rowproxy#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) that says 'Mostly follows “ordered dictionary” behavior'. I couldn't find what 'Mostly' means, but I found I couldn't set values, like `row['ultimate answer'] = 42`
Just using `dict()` doesn't preserve the order of the columns, but the following seems to:

    d = OrderedDict()
    # Add each item in order.
    for k, v in row.items():
        d.update({k: v})

Answer (score -2):

*Python 3.6.8+*

The builtin `str()` method automatically converts datetime.datetime objects to iso-8806-1.

```
print(json.dumps([dict(row.items()) for row in rows], default=str, indent="  "))
```

NOTE: The `default` func will only be applied to a value if there's an error so `int` and `float` values won't be converted... unless there's an error :).

Answer (score -3):

My take utilizing (too many?) dictionaries:

```
def serialize(_query):
#d = dictionary written to per row
#D = dictionary d is written to each time, then reset
#Master = dictionary of dictionaries; the id Key (int, unique from database) from D is used as the Key for the dictionary D entry in Master
Master = {}
D = {}
x = 0
for u in _query:
    d = u.__dict__
    D = {}
    for n in d.keys():
        if n != '_sa_instance_state':
            D[n] = d[n]
    x = d['id']
    Master[x] = D
return Master
```

Running with flask (including jsonify) and flask_sqlalchemy to print outputs as JSON.

Call the function with jsonify(serialize()).

Works with all SQLAlchemy queries I've tried so far (running SQLite3)

Comment: There's no need to rely on the class dictionary, attempting to filter out non-columns manually when the SQLAlchemy inspection system exists.