# SQLAlchemy returns tuple not dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've updated SQLAlchemy to 0.6 but it broke everything. I've noticed it returns tuple not a dictionary anymore. Here's a sample query:

```
query = session.query(User.id, User.username, User.email).filter(and_(User.id == id, User.username == username)).limit(1)
result = session.execute(query).fetchone()
```

This piece of code used to return a dictionary in 0.5.

My question is how can I return a dictionary?

Comment: Just curious: Why don't you do `session.query(User).get(id)` (assuming User.id is the primary key). Or `session.query(User).filter(User.id==id).filter(User.username==username).first()` if id is not a primary key. Do that, and you'll get back a User instance, and you can access the field values by attribute lookup.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958219/5320906).

Comment: One can access the fields with dot notation: `print(result.id, result.username, result.email)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work: 
`dict(zip(['id','username','email'],result))` (or you could use a dictionary comprehension if you're on Python 3.x).

Also, you don't need to call `session.execute` on a `session.query` object. You'll want to use the `.one()` method on it instead. This also obviates the need for the `.limit(1)` call hanging off the end of your query.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I use limit(1) because when I look at the SQL statement SQLALchemy creates for this code it doesn't include LIMIT 1 in the query.

Answer (score 47):

session.execute has never returned a dict, it returns a RowProxy object, that can be indexed *like* a dict using either integer keys for positional lookup, string keys for label based lookup up or Column objects to lookup the value of that column. The problem here is that `session.execute(query)` doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do. It converts the Query object to a Select statement, executes that and returns the result directly. The resultset doesn't know anything about ORM level features. What changed between 0.5 ad 0.6 is that ORM uses a different algorithm to label the columns in queries, it now prepends the table name to the label. So when previously `row['id']` happened to work, now `row['users_id']` works. In both cases `row[User.__table__.columns['id']]` works.

To execute ORM queries you should actually use the `.all()`, `.first()` and `.one()` methods or iterate over it or using numeric indexing. Query returns named tuple objects. Zip the tuple with its keys if you want a dict:

```
row = session.query(User.id, User.username, User.email)\
    .filter(and_(User.id == id, User.username == username)).first()
print("id=%s username=%s email=%s" % row) # positional
print(row.id, row.username) # by label
print(dict(zip(row.keys(), row))) # as a dict
```

Answer (score 17):

Are you sure it isn't a [ResultProxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=resultproxy#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) which pretends to be a tuple when you print it? Many objects in the ORM are not what their `__str__` function returns.

Comment: +1 I was totally being blindsided by what I was seeing until I read this. After I read, I just went ahead and tried using the field names and it worked perfectly! Saved me a lot of headache. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this using:

```
# Get a list os user_ids 
data_from_db = session.execute(select(User.id)).all()

# Parsing each Row object to a dict by "_mapping" attribute
return [dict(data._mapping) for data in data_from_db]
```