# SQLAlchemy convert SELECT query result to a list of dicts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I was using session.query, I was able to convert the result to a list of dicts :

```
my_query = session.query(table1,table2).filter(all_filters)
result_dict = [u.__dict__ for u in my_query.all()]
```

But now that I have to work with the `SELECT()` operation, how can I convert the results to a dict that looks like, for every row result :

`[{'Row1column1Name' : 'Row1olumn1Value', 'Row1column2Name' :'Row1Column2Value'},{'Row2column1Name' : 'Row2olumn1Value', 'Row2column2Name' : 'Row2Column2Value'},etc....]`.

This is my SELECT() code :

```
select = select([table1,table2]).where(all_filters)
res = conn.execute(select)
row = res.fetchone() #I have to use fetchone() because the query returns lots of rows
resultset=[]
while row is not None:
    row = res.fetchone()
    resultset.append(row)

print resultset
```

The result is :

```
[('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'),(.....),etc for each row]
```

I'm new to Python, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy returns tuple not dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828248/sqlalchemy-returns-tuple-not-dictionary)

Answer (score 31):

This seems to be a RowProxy object. Try:

```
row = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
```

Comment: thanks! But how can I use this with the `fetchone()`? I actually need to load one row at a time, when I do this : 
`while row is not None:
     row = res.fetchone()
     result = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
 `

It gives me the error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: Just use res.keys() since difference between fetchall() and fetchone() is that fetchone() returns first element of list returned by fetchall().

Comment: This does not give the result expected by OP

Answer (score 18):

You can typecast each row from a select result as either a dict or a tuple. What you've been seeing is the default behaviour, which is to represent the each row as a tuple. To typecast to a dict, modify your code like this:

```
select = select([table1, table2]).where(all_filters)
res = conn.execute(select)
resultset = []
for row in res:
    resultset.append(dict(row))
print resultset
```

This works nicely if you need to process the result one row at a time.

If you're happy to put all rows into a list in one go, list comprehension is a bit neater:

```
select = select([table1, table2]).where(all_filters)
res = conn.execute(select)
resultset = [dict(row) for row in res]
print resultset
```

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Fanti's answer, if you use a List Comprehension, you can produce the list of dicts all in one row. Here `results` is the result of my query.

```
records = [dict(zip(row.keys(), row)) for row in results]
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first query its better to use this approach for sqlalchemy KeyedTuple:

```
# Convert an instance of `sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple`
# to a dictionary
my_query = session.query(table1,table2).filter(all_filters)
result_dict = map(lambda q: q._asdict(), my_query)
```

OR

```
result_dict = map(lambda obj: dict(zip(obj.keys(), obj)), my_query)
```

For ResultProxy as earlier mentioned:

```
result_dict = dict(zip(row.keys(), row))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Make a function -**

```
def resultToDict(result):
    ds = []
    for rows in result:
        d = {}
        for row in rows:
            for col in row.__table__.columns:
                d[col.name] = str(getattr(row, col.name))
        ds.append(d)
    return ds
```

**Execute like this -**

```
resultToDict(my_query.all())
```

**Result -**

```
[
{'Row1column1Name' : 'Row1column1Value', 'Row1column2Name' : 'Row1Column2Value'},
{'Row2column1Name' : 'Row2column1Value', 'Row2column2Name' : 'Row2Column2Value'},
{'Row3column1Name' : 'Row3column1Value', 'Row3column2Name' : 'Row3Column2Value'},
etc....
]
```