# Fastapi pydantic validation: return items grouped by day

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I have a FastAPI application. I would like to provide an overview per day of the total steps someone is doing.

The database table contains following information:

```
id  activity     client_ip    duration  steps   date
--------------------------------------------------------------
8   Activity2    A.B.C.D      1         200     2021-12-11 13:45:00.887810
7   Activity1    A.B.C.D      1         100     2021-12-11 13:45:00.887810
6   Activity1    A.B.C.D      1         100     2021-12-10 13:43:58.887698
5   Activity2    K.L.M.N      2         400     2021-12-10 13:42:57.061950
4   Activity1    K.L.M.N      1         100     2021-12-09 13:34:36.951690
3   Activity4    A.B.C.D      23        500     2021-12-09 12:33:46.405082
2   Activity1    K.L.M.N      12        1200    2021-12-09 12:33:33.989297
1   Activity1    A.B.C.D      10        1000    2021-12-09 12:33:33.989297
```

I want to write a SQLAlchemy query that returns the total amount of steps (across all activities) per day per client. So for client A.B.C.D, it would look like:

```
day          sum
----------------
2021-12-11   300
2021-12-10   100
2021-12-09   1500
```

To achieve this, I have written the below query:

```
def total_steps_per_day_per_client_ip(db, client_ip):
    entries = (
        db.query(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", models.Entry.date), func.sum(models.Entry.total_steps).label("sum"))
        .filter_by(client_ip=client_ip)
        .group_by(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", models.Entry.date))
    ).all()

    return entries
```

This function returns `[('2021-12-09', 150), ('2021-12-10', 100), ('2021-12-11', 300)]`

I would like to return the below json object to my Vue client:

```
{
   day: 2021-12-11
   total_steps: 300
},
{
   day: 2021-12-10
   total_steps: 100
},
{
   day: 2021-12-09
   total_steps: 150
}
```

Therefore I have the following Fastapi route:

```
@app.get("/steps",response_model=schemas.TotalSteps)
async def steps(request: Request, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    totalsteps_perday = total_steps_per_day_per_client_ip(db, request.client.host)
    return totalsteps_perday
```

and in the schema's file I have defined `TotalSteps` as follows:

```
class TotalSteps(BaseModel):
    day: str
    totalsteps: int
```

When I hit the `/steps` URL, I'm getting pydantic validation errors:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for TotalSteps 
response -> day   
  field required (type=value_error.missing) 
response -> totalsteps   
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Comment: Maybe this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828248/sqlalchemy-returns-tuple-not-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add proper `label()` to each `func` in your query:

```
    entries = (
        db.query(
            func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", models.Entry.date).label("day"), 
            func.sum(models.Entry.total_steps).label("totalsteps"))
        .filter_by(client_ip=client_ip)
        .group_by(func.strftime("%Y-%m-%d", models.Entry.date))
    ).all()
```

FastAPI internally converts each result row to dict based on the labels or the column names by default and with your code it results in:

```
{
   'date': '2021-12-11',
   'sum': 300,
}
```

That's why pydantic model gives errors regarding missing fields

but you need it to be actually:

```
{
   'day': '2021-12-11',
   'totalsteps': 300,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a List as response model. I think that's what you want here.

```py
from typing import List
@app.get("/steps", response_model=List[schemas.TotalSteps])
```

If you now return a list of data from the handler, FastAPI will know how to serialize it into a JSON array.

You may also need to take additional configuration steps for your model

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from datetime import date

class TotalSteps(BaseModel):
    date: date = Field(..., alias='day')
    sum: int = Field(..., alias='total_steps')

   class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

Or you use directly the correct labels in your query function.