# How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

Django has some good automatic serialization of ORM models returned from DB to JSON format.

How to serialize SQLAlchemy query result to JSON format?

I tried `jsonpickle.encode` but it encodes query object itself.
I tried `json.dumps(items)` but it returns

```
TypeError: <Product('3', 'some name', 'some desc')> is not JSON serializable
```

Is it really so hard to serialize SQLAlchemy ORM objects to JSON /XML? Isn't there any default serializer for it? It's very common task to serialize ORM query results nowadays.

What I need is just to return JSON or XML data representation of SQLAlchemy query result.

SQLAlchemy objects query result in JSON/XML format is needed to be used in javascript datagird (JQGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: This is a workaround that works for me. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559808/why-is-object-of-type-decimal-is-not-json-serializable-when-using-marshmallo/58473528#58473528)

Comment: I must warn you that serializing many sqlalchemy models (such as a list of them) will be very slow. If you care about performance, select dictionaries instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58660606/2782670

Comment: On table models create a wrapper and in it define the to_dict method and write the coloumn data you want to serialize and use this wrapper to get the data from the database

Answer (score 177, accepted):

## A flat implementation

You could use something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            # an SQLAlchemy class
            fields = {}
            for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata']:
                data = obj.__getattribute__(field)
                try:
                    json.dumps(data) # this will fail on non-encodable values, like other classes
                    fields[field] = data
                except TypeError:
                    fields[field] = None
            # a json-encodable dict
            return fields

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

and then convert to JSON using:

```
c = YourAlchemyClass()
print json.dumps(c, cls=AlchemyEncoder)
```

It will ignore fields that are not encodable (set them to 'None').

It doesn't auto-expand relations (since this could lead to self-references, and loop forever).

## A recursive, non-circular implementation

If, however, you'd rather loop forever, you could use:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

def new_alchemy_encoder():
    _visited_objs = []

    class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, obj):
            if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
                # don't re-visit self
                if obj in _visited_objs:
                    return None
                _visited_objs.append(obj)

                # an SQLAlchemy class
                fields = {}
                for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata']:
                    fields[field] = obj.__getattribute__(field)
                # a json-encodable dict
                return fields

            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    return AlchemyEncoder
```

And then encode objects using:

```
print json.dumps(e, cls=new_alchemy_encoder(), check_circular=False)
```

This would encode all children, and all their children, and all their children... Potentially encode your entire database, basically. When it reaches something its encoded before, it will encode it as 'None'.

## A recursive, possibly-circular, selective implementation

Another alternative, probably better, is to be able to specify the fields you want to expand:

```
def new_alchemy_encoder(revisit_self = False, fields_to_expand = []):
    _visited_objs = []

    class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, obj):
            if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
                # don't re-visit self
                if revisit_self:
                    if obj in _visited_objs:
                        return None
                    _visited_objs.append(obj)

                # go through each field in this SQLalchemy class
                fields = {}
                for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata']:
                    val = obj.__getattribute__(field)

                    # is this field another SQLalchemy object, or a list of SQLalchemy objects?
                    if isinstance(val.__class__, DeclarativeMeta) or (isinstance(val, list) and len(val) > 0 and isinstance(val[0].__class__, DeclarativeMeta)):
                        # unless we're expanding this field, stop here
                        if field not in fields_to_expand:
                            # not expanding this field: set it to None and continue
                            fields[field] = None
                            continue

                    fields[field] = val
                # a json-encodable dict
                return fields

            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

    return AlchemyEncoder
```

You can now call it with:

```
print json.dumps(e, cls=new_alchemy_encoder(False, ['parents']), check_circular=False)
```

To only expand SQLAlchemy fields called 'parents', for example.

Comment: that's a great response, however I get a "could not encode "BaseQuery" whenever it hits a relationship with the non-flat methods, any ideas?

Comment: @SashaB How about targeting more granularly against cases where a relationship is repeated? For example, if I have `online_order` and `address`, both with a relationship to `user`, but `online_order` also has an relationship to `address`. If I wanted to serialize all of this, I'd have to include `address` in the `fields_to_expand`, but I wouldn't want to redundantly serialize `address` due to its relationship to both `user` and `online_order`.

Comment: @BenKilah Let me guess, you're using Flask-SqlAlchemy and your models are inheriting from db.Model, not Base. If that's the case, modify `for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata']:` so that it reads `for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata' and not x.startswith('query')]:`. Keep in mind this solution will prevent you from having a property/relationship with the name 'query'

Comment: same way like I did, but much more complex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask/37585632#37585632

Comment: You can use my solution https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer

Comment: And yet another solution https://wakatime.com/blog/32-part-1-sqlalchemy-models-to-json

Comment: I can suggest to use https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer
It is very fast and convenient to use

Comment: With your flat implementation, was it intended for you to display the JSON fields backwards from how they were created?

Comment: This was super helpful to me. Thank you! 
I needed datetime objects to be converted to strings so made this little tweak: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843304/9536012

Answer (score 373):

You could just output your object as a dictionary:

```
class User:
   def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

And then you use `User.as_dict()` to serialize your object.

As explained in [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)

Comment: @charlax, How'd I fix a DateTime? By using this I get 'datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 22, 16, 50, 11) is not JSON serializable' when I do json.dumps

Comment: It's the responsibility of the `JSONEncoder` object. You can subclass it to define your own encoder for some object, including datetime. Note that `Flask`, for instance, support encoding datetime in JSON out of the box (with the latest version).

Comment: If you use sqlalchemy's "declarative" method you can add something like this to a custom Base class - this is pretty handy as you can then call my_orm_object.toDict() on any ORM object you have. Similarly you can define a .toJSON() method which uses your toDict method and a custom encoder for handling dates, blobs etc

Comment: How do I handle eager loaded relationships?

Comment: I would avoid dumping relationships, and rely on client-side joins. If you absolutely want to include relationships, you can either have an explicit list of them and call `as_dict` on them, or you could imagine using `operator.attrgetter` and being explicit about everything. There's a way to get relationships on a model programatically as well.

Comment: to also support datetime: `return {c.name: unicode(getattr(self, c.name)) for c in self.__table__.columns}`

Comment: no need to right a your own as_dict() conversion, the row in resultset has an internal __dict__ method.  Try this:
``
    import json
    rs = YourModel.query.all()
    s = json.dumps([r.__dict__ for r in rs], default=alchemyencoder)
    print "result: " + s
``

Comment: This doesn't work if your class variables are not the same as your column names. Any idea how to get the class names instead?

Comment: But how to write the deserializer or this model? Do I have to write code for every Column class?

Comment: @JamesBurke - check "More difficult case" section of (my) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47213628/2272638). But, something like: `{a.key: rowproxy[a.class_attribute.name] for a in User.__mapper__.attrs}`

Comment: For Python 3 users, @Shoham's answer needs a small change: `return {c.name: str(getattr(self, c.name)) for c in self.__table__.columns}`

Comment: Great answer. Is there a way to use it with [flask.json.jsonify()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify) to set headers et al properly?

Answer (score 186):

## Python 3.7+ and Flask 1.1+ can use the built-in [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) package

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@dataclass
class User(db.Model):
  id: int
  email: str

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, auto_increment=True)
  email = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)


@app.route('/users/')
def users():
  users = User.query.all()
  return jsonify(users)  


if __name__ == "__main__":
  users = User(email="user1@gmail.com"), User(email="user2@gmail.com")
  db.create_all()
  db.session.add_all(users)
  db.session.commit()
  app.run()
```

The `/users/` route will now return a list of users.

```
[
  {"email": "user1@gmail.com", "id": 1},
  {"email": "user2@gmail.com", "id": 2}
]
```

### Auto-serialize related models

```
@dataclass
class Account(db.Model):
  id: int
  users: User

  id = db.Column(db.Integer)
  users = db.relationship(User)  # User model would need a db.ForeignKey field
```

The response from `jsonify(account)` would be this.

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "users":[  
      {  
         "email":"user1@gmail.com",
         "id":1
      },
      {  
         "email":"user2@gmail.com",
         "id":2
      }
   ]
}
```

### Overwrite the default JSON Encoder

```
from flask.json import JSONEncoder


class CustomJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
  "Add support for serializing timedeltas"

  def default(o):
    if type(o) == datetime.timedelta:
      return str(o)
    if type(o) == datetime.datetime:
      return o.isoformat()
    return super().default(o)

app.json_encoder = CustomJSONEncoder
```

Comment: This looks like the right kind of simple. Does it also work for deserialization?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, also, it do not seem to work with `dump = json.dumps(query_result)`, but that's okay, I use `return make_response(jsonify(query_result), 200)`.

Comment: Note that `id: int = Column` will work, but `id = Column` won't, it seem like YOU HAVE TO declare static typing for the json to serialized the field, otherwise you get an empty `{}` object.

Comment: @tom thanks, but wasn't actually requesting any help (I have no issue), I am using `make_response` to be able to change the response code, and maybe json.dumps wasn't working due to the typing missing on my model.

Comment: This worked for me, why isn't this the accepted answer? I have been playing around app_context for hours to to get this to work with Flask-Marshmallow.

Comment: Nice answer! However, the datetime format is not so nice (e.g. `"Thu, 19 Dec 2019 07:48:28 GMT"`). Is there a way to get the isoformat?

Comment: @MartinThoma you could over-ride the default JSON encoder that Flask uses. I updated the example above to demonstrate how you can control the serialization of datetime objects to use ISO format.

Comment: wow, it work for me, thank's.

However i have question here, , i use `__tablename__` property to named my model, how to except this property.

thank's :)

Comment: Worked for me as well. Note that if you're on Python 3.6, you'll want to just install the package: `pipenv install dataclasses`. And then it'll work just fine.

Comment: Nice. Aside, for related models: given the need for a true class in `users: User`, I could not find a way to _also_ use the reverse relation, from User to Account, without running into circular dependencies. (I assume that preventing circular dependencies may also be why SQLAlchemy supports string values for class names in, e.g., `users = db.relationship('User', back_populates = 'accounts')`. But that won't help while declaring the attributes, where `User` would then need some `accounts: Account` attribute.)

Comment: This demo worked for me.  But not until I moved the db.create_all() to directly below the definition of the table.  And then below db.create_all() I then added the users.

Comment: Worked for me with the following modifications (Flask 1.1.2):  add: import datetime, modified: def default(o) to: def default(self, o).

Comment: I like the elegance of this. It's easy to define what should be included in the JSON. Only caveat for me was: Decimal column type does not work, and obviously any relationship tables also need to be dataclass'ed to work.

Comment: as everyone has already stated: amazingly straightforward and helpful answer! has anyone gotten around the Decimal or Numeric() column types and decimal not being json serializable error?

Comment: @JohnBlythe were you able to try overwriting the default json encoder? I think that should do it for you.

Comment: To make pylance happy, I had to use `cast()` e.g. `id: int = cast(int, Column(Integer))`

Comment: If your app uses floats/decimals then you'll want to add another case to the custom json encoder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707102/3873308

Comment: This is awesome. I've been messing around with Marshmallow and really struggling. This is way simpler and just works. I agree with others that this should be the accepted answer. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This method can work more generally without using Flask. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75390554/8605685).

Comment: I was not successfull when trying to implement this answer. But, using the SQLAlchemy Automatic Schema worked... I think.

Answer (score 69):

You can convert a RowProxy to a dict like this:

```
 d = dict(row.items())
```

Then serialize that to JSON ( you will have to specify an encoder for things like `datetime` values )
It's not that hard if you just want one record ( and not a full hierarchy of related records ).

```
json.dumps([(dict(row.items())) for row in rs])
```

Comment: This works for my custom sql query     with db.engine.connect() as con:
        rs = con.execute(sql)

Comment: This is much more simple and works. What is the difference between this answer and the accepted answer?

Answer (score 61):

I recommend using [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/). It allows you to create serializers to represent your model instances with support to relations and nested objects.

Here is a truncated example from their docs. Take the ORM model, `Author`:

```py
class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first = db.Column(db.String(80))
    last = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

A marshmallow schema for that class is constructed like this:

```py
class AuthorSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    first = fields.Str()
    last = fields.Str()
    formatted_name = fields.Method("format_name", dump_only=True)

    def format_name(self, author):
        return "{}, {}".format(author.last, author.first)
```

...and used like this:

```py
author_schema = AuthorSchema()
author_schema.dump(Author.query.first())
```

...would produce an output like this:

```
{
        "first": "Tim",
        "formatted_name": "Peters, Tim",
        "id": 1,
        "last": "Peters"
}
```

Have a look at their full [Flask-SQLAlchemy Example](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#quotes-api-flask-sqlalchemy).

A library called `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` specifically integrates SQLAlchemy and marshmallow. In that library, the schema for the `Author` model described above looks like this:

```py
class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

The integration allows the field types to be inferred from the SQLAlchemy `Column` types.

[marshmallow-sqlalchemy here.](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I also found http://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ which simplifies the schema generation

Answer (score 19):

You can use introspection of SqlAlchemy as this :

```
mysql = SQLAlchemy()
from sqlalchemy import inspect

class Contacts(mysql.Model):  
    __tablename__ = 'CONTACTS'
    id = mysql.Column(mysql.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    last_name = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    phone = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    email = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    street = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    zip_code = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    city = mysql.Column(mysql.String(128), nullable=False)
    def toDict(self):
        return { c.key: getattr(self, c.key) for c in inspect(self).mapper.column_attrs }

@app.route('/contacts',methods=['GET'])
def getContacts():
    contacts = Contacts.query.all()
    contactsArr = []
    for contact in contacts:
        contactsArr.append(contact.toDict()) 
    return jsonify(contactsArr)

@app.route('/contacts/<int:id>',methods=['GET'])
def getContact(id):
    contact = Contacts.query.get(id)
    return jsonify(contact.toDict())
```

Get inspired from an answer here : 
    [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)

Comment: In terms of minimal solutions, I combined the toDict() above with tom's CustomJSONEncoder (note slight modifications) to get datetimes into ISO format.   Ah the power of stack overflow!

Comment: i found the magic ingredient in this piece of  code  `contact.toDict()`

Answer (score 14):

Here's one way to make your SqlAlchemy objects serializable:
implement a custom `JSONEncoder` and add it to the base class:

Usage:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from flask.ext.jsontools import JsonSerializableBase

Base = declarative_base(cls=(DynamicJSONEncoder,))

class User(Base):
    #...
```

Now the `User` model is magically serializable.

Here's one way to implement a custom JSONEncoder: it will allow you to customize how an instance is represented in JSON by implementing the `__json__()` method:

```py
from flask.json import JSONEncoder

class DynamicJSONEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    """ JSON encoder for custom classes:

        Uses __json__() method if available to prepare the object.
        Especially useful for SQLAlchemy models
    """

    def default(self, o):
        # Custom JSON-encodeable objects
        if hasattr(o, '__json__'):
            return o.__json__()

        # Default
        return super().default(o)
```

Comment: This only solves half the problem, as it only serializes a single row. How to serialize the whole query result?

Comment: @SteveBennett use the jsontools' [jsonapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flask_jsontools/#jsonresponse) to encode the response. That will automatically encode the return object

Comment: I have a very simple sqlalchemy model, and I'm getting: TypeError: <ORM.State object at 0x03577A50> is not JSON serializable

Comment: It worked eventually by explicitly calling __json__() on my model object: return my_object.__json__()

Comment: The library does not work with Flask 1.0 and above, as `import flask.ext.whatever` is no longer supported in Flask 1.0.

Comment: To provide some useful info and save some googling, it appears you need to use `from flask_jsontools import JsonSerializableBase` instead of `from flask.ext.jsontools import JsonSerializableBase` now.

Comment: Please help a noob - _Now the User model is magically serializable_ so once I what code do I use to return `BaseQuery` as JSON?

Comment: @Matej and others! please add this to your flask app.py file: `app.json_encoder = DynamicJSONEncoder` now, you can return your models directly without using `__json__()`!

Comment: Also, in first code block should be: Base = declarative_base(cls=(JsonSerializableBase,))

Answer (score 14):

For security reasons you should never return all the model's fields. I prefer to selectively choose them.

Flask's json encoding now supports UUID, datetime and relationships (and added `query` and `query_class` for flask_sqlalchemy `db.Model` class). I've updated the encoder as follows:

> app/json_encoder.py

```
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta
    from flask import json


    class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            if isinstance(o.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
                data = {}
                fields = o.__json__() if hasattr(o, '__json__') else dir(o)
                for field in [f for f in fields if not f.startswith('_') and f not in ['metadata', 'query', 'query_class']]:
                    value = o.__getattribute__(field)
                    try:
                        json.dumps(value)
                        data[field] = value
                    except TypeError:
                        data[field] = None
                return data
            return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

> `app/__init__.py`

```
# json encoding
from app.json_encoder import AlchemyEncoder
app.json_encoder = AlchemyEncoder
```

With this I can optionally add a `__json__` property that returns the list of fields I wish to encode:

> `app/models.py`

```
class Queue(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    song_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('song.id'), unique=True, nullable=False)
    song = db.relationship('Song', lazy='joined')
    type = db.Column(db.String(20), server_default=u'audio/mpeg')
    src = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    def __init__(self, song):
        self.song = song
        self.src = song.full_path

    def __json__(self):
        return ['song', 'src', 'type', 'created_at']
```

I add @jsonapi to my view, return the resultlist and then my output is as follows:

```
[

{

    "created_at": "Thu, 23 Jul 2015 11:36:53 GMT",
    "song": 

        {
            "full_path": "/static/music/Audioslave/Audioslave [2002]/1 Cochise.mp3",
            "id": 2,
            "path_name": "Audioslave/Audioslave [2002]/1 Cochise.mp3"
        },
    "src": "/static/music/Audioslave/Audioslave [2002]/1 Cochise.mp3",
    "type": "audio/mpeg"
}

]
```

Comment: Beautiful! Once again, proof that sometimes you don't need a fat package for every stupid little task--that learning DSL can be harder than doing it the "hard" way. I looked at many many JSON and REST packages before landing here. True, this still requires a package, _flask\_jsontools_ (to add `@jsonapi` to `@app.route` in _views.py_ etc), but I love the simplicity of it. I think it is cheap Flask added datetime but not date so I added it myself to _json\_encoder.py_: `value=...`^`if isinstance(value, date):`^`data[field] = datetime.combine(value, time.min).isoformat()`^`else:`^`try:...`

Answer (score 7):

A more detailed explanation. 
In your model, add:

```
def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: str(getattr(self, c.name)) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

The `str()` is for python 3 so if using python 2 use `unicode()`. It should help deserialize dates. You can remove it if not dealing with those.

You can now query the database like this

```
some_result = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first().as_dict()
```

`First()` is needed to avoid weird errors. `as_dict()` will now deserialize the result. After deserialization, it is ready to be turned to json

```
jsonify(some_result)
```

Comment: it will raise an error if id has uuid type!

Answer (score 3):

While the original question goes back awhile, the number of answers here (and my own experiences) suggest it's a non-trivial question with a lot of different approaches of varying complexity with different trade-offs.

That's why I built the [SQLAthanor](https://github.com/insightindustry/sqlathanor) library that extends SQLAlchemy's declarative ORM with configurable serialization/de-serialization support that you might want to take a look at.

The library supports:

- Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6.
- SQLAlchemy versions 0.9 and higher
- serialization/de-serialization to/from JSON, CSV, YAML, and Python `dict`
- serialization/de-serialization of columns/attributes, relationships, hybrid properties, and association proxies
- enabling and disabling of serialization for particular formats and columns/relationships/attributes (e.g. you want to support an *inbound* `password` value, but never include an *outbound* one)
- pre-serialization and post-deserialization value processing (for validation or type coercion)
- a pretty straightforward syntax that is both Pythonic and seamlessly consistent with SQLAlchemy's own approach

You can check out the (I hope!) comprehensive docs here: https://sqlathanor.readthedocs.io/en/latest

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Custom serialization and deserialization.

**"from_json"** (class method) builds a Model object based on json data.

**"deserialize"** could be called only on instance, and merge all data from json into Model instance.

**"serialize"** - recursive serialization

**__write_only__** property is needed to define write only properties ("password_hash" for example).

```
class Serializable(object):
    __exclude__ = ('id',)
    __include__ = ()
    __write_only__ = ()

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json, selfObj=None):
        if selfObj is None:
            self = cls()
        else:
            self = selfObj
        exclude = (cls.__exclude__ or ()) + Serializable.__exclude__
        include = cls.__include__ or ()
        if json:
            for prop, value in json.iteritems():
                # ignore all non user data, e.g. only
                if (not (prop in exclude) | (prop in include)) and isinstance(
                        getattr(cls, prop, None), QueryableAttribute):
                    setattr(self, prop, value)
        return self

    def deserialize(self, json):
        if not json:
            return None
        return self.__class__.from_json(json, selfObj=self)

    @classmethod
    def serialize_list(cls, object_list=[]):
        output = []
        for li in object_list:
            if isinstance(li, Serializable):
                output.append(li.serialize())
            else:
                output.append(li)
        return output

    def serialize(self, **kwargs):

        # init write only props
        if len(getattr(self.__class__, '__write_only__', ())) == 0:
            self.__class__.__write_only__ = ()
        dictionary = {}
        expand = kwargs.get('expand', ()) or ()
        prop = 'props'
        if expand:
            # expand all the fields
            for key in expand:
                getattr(self, key)
        iterable = self.__dict__.items()
        is_custom_property_set = False
        # include only properties passed as parameter
        if (prop in kwargs) and (kwargs.get(prop, None) is not None):
            is_custom_property_set = True
            iterable = kwargs.get(prop, None)
        # loop trough all accessible properties
        for key in iterable:
            accessor = key
            if isinstance(key, tuple):
                accessor = key[0]
            if not (accessor in self.__class__.__write_only__) and not accessor.startswith('_'):
                # force select from db to be able get relationships
                if is_custom_property_set:
                    getattr(self, accessor, None)
                if isinstance(self.__dict__.get(accessor), list):
                    dictionary[accessor] = self.__class__.serialize_list(object_list=self.__dict__.get(accessor))
                # check if those properties are read only
                elif isinstance(self.__dict__.get(accessor), Serializable):
                    dictionary[accessor] = self.__dict__.get(accessor).serialize()
                else:
                    dictionary[accessor] = self.__dict__.get(accessor)
        return dictionary
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [built-in serializer](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/serializer.html) in SQLAlchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps
obj = MyAlchemyObject()
# serialize object
serialized_obj = dumps(obj)

# deserialize object
obj = loads(serialized_obj)
```

If you're transferring the object between sessions, remember to detach the object from the current session using `session.expunge(obj)`.
To attach it again, just do `session.add(obj)`.

Comment: Nifty, but does not convert to JSON.

Comment: **For JSON 'serialization' check out marshmallow-sqlalchemy**. Definitely the best solution when you're exposing objects to clients. https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io

Comment: The serializer module is only appropriate for query structures. It is not needed for: instances of user-defined classes. These contain no references to engines, sessions or expression constructs in the typical case and can be serialized directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that lets you select the relations you want to include in your output as deep as you would like to go.
NOTE: This is a complete re-write taking a dict/str as an arg rather than a list. fixes some stuff..

```
def deep_dict(self, relations={}):
    """Output a dict of an SA object recursing as deep as you want.

    Takes one argument, relations which is a dictionary of relations we'd
    like to pull out. The relations dict items can be a single relation
    name or deeper relation names connected by sub dicts

    Example:
        Say we have a Person object with a family relationship
            person.deep_dict(relations={'family':None})
        Say the family object has homes as a relation then we can do
            person.deep_dict(relations={'family':{'homes':None}})
            OR
            person.deep_dict(relations={'family':'homes'})
        Say homes has a relation like rooms you can do
            person.deep_dict(relations={'family':{'homes':'rooms'}})
            and so on...
    """
    mydict =  dict((c, str(a)) for c, a in
                    self.__dict__.items() if c != '_sa_instance_state')
    if not relations:
        # just return ourselves
        return mydict

    # otherwise we need to go deeper
    if not isinstance(relations, dict) and not isinstance(relations, str):
        raise Exception("relations should be a dict, it is of type {}".format(type(relations)))

    # got here so check and handle if we were passed a dict
    if isinstance(relations, dict):
        # we were passed deeper info
        for left, right in relations.items():
            myrel = getattr(self, left)
            if isinstance(myrel, list):
                mydict[left] = [rel.deep_dict(relations=right) for rel in myrel]
            else:
                mydict[left] = myrel.deep_dict(relations=right)
    # if we get here check and handle if we were passed a string
    elif isinstance(relations, str):
        # passed a single item
        myrel = getattr(self, relations)
        left = relations
        if isinstance(myrel, list):
            mydict[left] = [rel.deep_dict(relations=None)
                                 for rel in myrel]
        else:
            mydict[left] = myrel.deep_dict(relations=None)

    return mydict
```

so for an example using person/family/homes/rooms... turning it into json all you need is

```
json.dumps(person.deep_dict(relations={'family':{'homes':'rooms'}}))
```

Comment: This is fine I think to just put in your base class so that all objects will have it. I'll leave the json encoding to you...

Comment: Note that this version will get all list relations so be cautious providing relations with a ton of items...

Answer (score 2):

```
step1:
class CNAME:
   ...
   def as_dict(self):
       return {item.name: getattr(self, item.name) for item in self.__table__.columns}

step2:
list = []
for data in session.query(CNAME).all():
    list.append(data.as_dict())

step3:
return jsonify(list)
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's a old post, Maybe I didn't answer the question above, but I want to talk about my serialization, at least it works for me.

I use FastAPI,SqlAlchemy and MySQL, but I don't use orm model;

```
# from sqlalchemy import create_engine
# from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
# engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, pool_pre_ping=True)
# SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
```

Serialization code

```py
import decimal
import datetime


def alchemy_encoder(obj):
    """JSON encoder function for SQLAlchemy special classes."""
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        return obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    elif isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(obj)

import json
from sqlalchemy import text

# db is SessionLocal() object 

app_sql = 'SELECT * FROM app_info ORDER BY app_id LIMIT :page,:page_size'

# The next two are the parameters passed in
page = 1
page_size = 10

# execute sql and return a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy'> object
app_list = db.execute(text(app_sql), {'page': page, 'page_size': page_size})

# serialize
res = json.loads(json.dumps([dict(r) for r in app_list], default=alchemy_encoder))
```

If it doesn't work, please ignore my answer. I refer to it here

https://codeandlife.com/2014/12/07/sqlalchemy-results-to-json-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 2):

install simplejson by
`pip install simplejson` and the create a class

```
class Serialise(object):

    def _asdict(self):
        """
        Serialization logic for converting entities using flask's jsonify

        :return: An ordered dictionary
        :rtype: :class:`collections.OrderedDict`
        """

        result = OrderedDict()
        # Get the columns
        for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
            if isinstance(getattr(self, key), datetime):
                result["x"] = getattr(self, key).timestamp() * 1000
                result["timestamp"] = result["x"]
            else:
                result[key] = getattr(self, key)

        return result
```

and inherit this class to every orm classes so that this `_asdict` function gets registered to every ORM class and boom.
And use jsonify anywhere

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.7+ in 2023

You can add the [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) decorator to your model and define a custom JSON serializer, then [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) will work (by providing the custom encoder to `cls`). In the example below, `db_row` is an instance of the `DB` class:

```
json.dumps(db_row, cls=models.CustomJSONEncoder)
```

```
{"id": 25, "name": "A component", "author": "Bob", "modified": "2023-02-08T11:49:15.675837"}
```

The custom JSON serializer can be easily modified to make it compatible with any type that isn't natively JSON serializable.

### models.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import dataclasses
import json
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from database import Base


@dataclasses.dataclass # <<-- add this decorator 
class DB(Base):
    """Model used for SQLite database entries."""

    __tablename__ = "components"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name: str = Column(String)
    author: str = Column(String)
    modified: datetime = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.utcnow)


class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder): # <<-- Add this custom encoder 
    """Custom JSON encoder for the DB class."""

    def default(self, o):
        if dataclasses.is_dataclass(o): # this serializes anything dataclass can handle  
            return dataclasses.asdict(o)
        if isinstance(o, datetime): # this adds support for datetime
            return o.isoformat()
        return super().default(o)
```

To further extend it for any non-serializable type you might use in your database, add another `if` statement to the custom encoder class that returns something serializable (e.g. `str`).

Answer (score 1):

It is not so straighforward. I wrote some code to do this. I'm still working on it, and it uses the MochiKit framework. It basically translates compound objects between Python and Javascript using a proxy and registered JSON converters.

Browser side for database objects is [db.js](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/media/js/db.js)
It needs the basic Python proxy source in [proxy.js](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/media/js/proxy.js).

On the Python side there is the base [proxy module](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/WWW/pycopia/WWW/json.py).
Then finally the SqlAlchemy object encoder in [webserver.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/webservice.py).
It also depends on metadata extractors found in the [models.py](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/storage/pycopia/db/models.py) file.

Comment: Quite complicated from the first glance... What I need - is to get SQLAlchemy objects query result in JSON/XML format to use it in javascript datagird (JQGrid http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Comment: Sometimes problems are more complicated than you exect at first glance... This handles objects returned as foreign keys, and tries to avoid the infinite recursion that happens with deeply nested relations.  However, you could probably write some custom queries that return base types only and serialize those with simplejson directly.

Comment: Right, maybe I'll really go with querying for dicts using SQLAlchemy and will use benefits of ORM performing save/update actions only.

Answer (score 1):

```
def alc2json(row):
    return dict([(col, str(getattr(row,col))) for col in row.__table__.columns.keys()])
```

I thought I'd play a little code golf with this one.

FYI: I am using [automap_base](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html) since we have a separately designed schema according to business requirements. I just started using SQLAlchemy today but the documentation states that automap_base is an extension to declarative_base which seems to be the typical paradigm in the SQLAlchemy ORM so I believe this should work.

It does not get fancy with following foreign keys per [Tjorriemorrie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184379/tjorriemorrie)'s solution, but it simply matches columns to values and handles Python types by str()-ing the column values. Our values consist Python datetime.time and decimal.Decimal class type results so it gets the job done.

Hope this helps any passers-by!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is quite an older post. I took solution given by @SashaB and modified as per my need.

I added following things to it:

1. Field ignore list: A list of fields to be ignored while serializing
2. Field replace list: A dictionary containing field names to be replaced by values while serializing.
3. Removed methods and BaseQuery getting serialized

My code is as follows:

```
def alchemy_json_encoder(revisit_self = False, fields_to_expand = [], fields_to_ignore = [], fields_to_replace = {}):
   """
   Serialize SQLAlchemy result into JSon
   :param revisit_self: True / False
   :param fields_to_expand: Fields which are to be expanded for including their children and all
   :param fields_to_ignore: Fields to be ignored while encoding
   :param fields_to_replace: Field keys to be replaced by values assigned in dictionary
   :return: Json serialized SQLAlchemy object
   """
   _visited_objs = []
   class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
      def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            # don't re-visit self
            if revisit_self:
                if obj in _visited_objs:
                    return None
                _visited_objs.append(obj)

            # go through each field in this SQLalchemy class
            fields = {}
            for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata' and x not in fields_to_ignore]:
                val = obj.__getattribute__(field)
                # is this field method defination, or an SQLalchemy object
                if not hasattr(val, "__call__") and not isinstance(val, BaseQuery):
                    field_name = fields_to_replace[field] if field in fields_to_replace else field
                    # is this field another SQLalchemy object, or a list of SQLalchemy objects?
                    if isinstance(val.__class__, DeclarativeMeta) or \
                            (isinstance(val, list) and len(val) > 0 and isinstance(val[0].__class__, DeclarativeMeta)):
                        # unless we're expanding this field, stop here
                        if field not in fields_to_expand:
                            # not expanding this field: set it to None and continue
                            fields[field_name] = None
                            continue

                    fields[field_name] = val
            # a json-encodable dict
            return fields

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
   return AlchemyEncoder
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

following code will serialize sqlalchemy result to json.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


def asdict(self):
    result = OrderedDict()
    for key in self.__mapper__.c.keys():
        if getattr(self, key) is not None:
            result[key] = str(getattr(self, key))
        else:
            result[key] = getattr(self, key)
    return result


def to_array(all_vendors):
    v = [ ven.asdict() for ven in all_vendors ]
    return json.dumps(v)
```

Calling fun,

```
def all_products():
    all_products = Products.query.all()
    return to_array(all_products)
```

Answer (score 1):

The AlchemyEncoder is wonderful but sometimes fails with Decimal values. Here is an improved encoder that solves the decimal problem -

```
class AlchemyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
# To serialize SQLalchemy objects 
def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
        model_fields = {}
        for field in [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith('_') and x != 'metadata']:
            data = obj.__getattribute__(field)
            print data
            try:
                json.dumps(data)  # this will fail on non-encodable values, like other classes
                model_fields[field] = data
            except TypeError:
                model_fields[field] = None
        return model_fields
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return float(obj)
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using sqlalchemy to connect to a db I this is a simple solution which is highly configurable. Use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

#sqlalchemy engine configuration
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine....

def my_function():
  #read in from sql directly into a pandas dataframe
  #check the pandas documentation for additional config options
  sql_DF = pd.read_sql_table("table_name", con=engine)

  # "orient" is optional here but allows you to specify the json formatting you require
  sql_json = sql_DF.to_json(orient="index")

  return sql_json
```

Answer (score 1):

(Tiny tweak on [Sasha B's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1332819/sasha-b) really excellent answer)

This specifically converts datetime objects to strings which in the original answer would be converted to `None`:

```
# Standard library imports
from datetime import datetime
import json

# 3rd party imports
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

class JsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            dict = {}

            # Remove invalid fields and just get the column attributes
            columns = [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith("_") and x != "metadata"]

            for column in columns:
                value = obj.__getattribute__(column)

                try:
                    json.dumps(value)
                    dict[column] = value
                except TypeError:
                    if isinstance(value, datetime):
                        dict[column] = value.__str__()
                    else:
                        dict[column] = None
            return dict

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SqlToDict:
    def __init__(self, data) -> None:
        self.data = data

    def to_timestamp(self, date):
        if isinstance(date, datetime):
            return int(datetime.timestamp(date))
        else:
            return date

    def to_dict(self) -> List:
        arr = []
        for i in self.data:
            keys = [*i.keys()]
            values = [*i]
            values = [self.to_timestamp(d) for d in values]
            arr.append(dict(zip(keys, values)))
        return arr
```

For example:

```
SqlToDict(data).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Very late 2023

### but Faster than json method with: O[n] and 2n space req

My implementation also supports Type Checking and ability to hide some attributes which can trim unnecessary data. and optional debug flag to inspect contents. uses python 3.10 walrus operator.

```
def obj_to_dict(obj, remove=['_sa_instance_state'], debug=False):
    result = {}

    if type(obj).__name__ == "Row":
        return dict(obj)

    for k in (obj := obj.__dict__):
        if k not in remove:
            result[key] = obj[k]

    print(result) if debug else None
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Flask, this works and handles datatime fields, transforming a field of type
`'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 22, 15, 40)` into
`"time": "2018-03-22 15:40:00"`:

```
obj = {c.name: str(getattr(self, c.name)) for c in self.__table__.columns}

# This to get the JSON body
return json.dumps(obj)

# Or this to get a response object
return jsonify(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The built in serializer chokes with utf-8 cannot decode invalid start byte for some inputs.  Instead, I went with:

```
def row_to_dict(row):
    temp = row.__dict__
    temp.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)
    return temp


def rows_to_list(rows):
    ret_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        ret_rows.append(row_to_dict(row))
    return ret_rows


@website_blueprint.route('/api/v1/some/endpoint', methods=['GET'])
def some_api():
    '''
    /some_endpoint
    '''
    rows = rows_to_list(SomeModel.query.all())
    response = app.response_class(
        response=jsonplus.dumps(rows),
        status=200,
        mimetype='application/json'
    )
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a class like this

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Table


class Custom:
    """Some custom logic here!"""

    __table__: Table  # def for mypy

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):  # pylint: disable=no-self-argument
        return cls.__name__  # pylint: disable= no-member

    def to_dict(self) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        """Serializes only column data."""
        return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

Base = declarative_base(cls=Custom)

class MyOwnTable(Base):
    #COLUMNS!
```

With that all objects have the `to_dict` method

Answer (score 0):

This is a `JSONEncoder` version that preserves model column order and only keeps recursively defined column and relationship fields. It also formats most JSON unserializable types:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

import arrow
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta

class SQLAlchemyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """
    SQLAlchemy ORM JSON Encoder
    If you have a "backref" relationship defined in your SQLAlchemy model,
    this encoder raises a ValueError to stop an infinite loop.
    """

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return arrow.get(obj).isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, set):
            return sorted(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj.__class__, DeclarativeMeta):
            for attribute, relationship in obj.__mapper__.relationships.items():
                if isinstance(relationship.__getattribute__("backref"), tuple):
                    raise ValueError(
                        f'{obj.__class__} object has a "backref" relationship '
                        "that would cause an infinite loop!"
                    )
            dictionary = {}
            column_names = [column.name for column in obj.__table__.columns]
            for key in column_names:
                value = obj.__getattribute__(key)
                if isinstance(value, datetime):
                    value = arrow.get(value).isoformat()
                elif isinstance(value, Decimal):
                    value = float(value)
                elif isinstance(value, set):
                    value = sorted(value)
                dictionary[key] = value
            for key in [
                attribute
                for attribute in dir(obj)
                if not attribute.startswith("_")
                and attribute != "metadata"
                and attribute not in column_names
            ]:
                value = obj.__getattribute__(key)
                dictionary[key] = value
            return dictionary

        return super().default(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this package succesfully: https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer

You can just do this on the model:

```
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin

class SomeModel(db.Model, SerializerMixin):
    ...
```

It adds to_dict that is fully recuresive:

```
item = SomeModel.query.filter(...).one()
result = item.to_dict()
```

It lets you make rules to avoid infinite recursion:

```
result = item.to_dict(rules=('-somefield', '-some_relation.nested_one.another_nested_one'))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html

```
from flask_restplus import fields, Namespace, marshal
api = Namespace("Student data")
db_data = Student_details.query.all()
data_marshal_obj = api.model(" Data", {
    "id": fields.String(),
    "number": fields.Integer(),
    "house_name": fields.String(),
 })
data_in_json_serialize =  marshal(db_data, data_marshal_obj)}
print(type(data_in_json_serialize )) #  <class 'dict'>
```

### customised serialize marshalling in flask restpluse

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, I came up with my own solution as below

```
def to_dict(self):
    keys = self.__mapper__.attrs.keys()
    attrs = vars(self)
    return { k : attrs[k]  for k in keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

a dynamic way to add `as_dict` method to any model

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

def implement_as_dict(model):
    if not hasattr(model,"as_dict"):
        column_names=[]
        imodel = inspect(model)
        for c in imodel.columns:
            column_names.append(c.key)

        #define model.as_dict()
        def as_dict(self):
            d = {}
            for c in column_names:
                d[c] = getattr(self,c)
            return d

        setattr(model,"as_dict",as_dict)

#model definition
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
# adding as_dict definition to model
implement_as_dict(User)
```

then you can use

```
user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='rick').first() 

user.as_dict()
#sample output 
{"id":1,"name":"rick"}
```

Answer (score -1):

While using some raw sql and undefined objects, using `cursor.description` appeared to get what I was looking for:

```
with connection.cursor() as cur:
    print(query)
    cur.execute(query)
    for item in cur.fetchall():
        row = {column.name: item[i] for i, column in enumerate(cur.description)}
        print(row)
```

Answer (score -2):

My take utilizing (too many?) dictionaries:

```
def serialize(_query):
    #d = dictionary written to per row
    #D = dictionary d is written to each time, then reset
    #Master = dictionary of dictionaries; the id Key (int, unique from database) 
    from D is used as the Key for the dictionary D entry in Master
    Master = {}
    D = {}
    x = 0
    for u in _query:
        d = u.__dict__
        D = {}
        for n in d.keys():
           if n != '_sa_instance_state':
                    D[n] = d[n]
        x = d['id']
        Master[x] = D
    return Master
```

Running with flask (including jsonify) and flask_sqlalchemy to print outputs as JSON.

Call the function with jsonify(serialize()).

Works with all SQLAlchemy queries I've tried so far (running SQLite3)

Answer (score -3):

if you are using Flask and just want to make a quick query:

```
def get_cats():
    sql = text("select * from cat")
    sql_params = {}
    result = db.session.execute(sql, sql_params)
    row_list = result.fetchall()
    data = [dict(r) for r in row_list]

    response = jsonify({
        'data': [{
            'categorias': data
        }]
    })
    
    return response
```