# backup mysql database on pythonanywhere

Tags: mysql, pythonanywhere

I am new to MySQL and know how to use mysqldump utility to backup a database. However, I think it is not installed on pythonanywhere. I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can back up mysql databases that I create on pythonanywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[update]

We've now made the `mysqldump` binary available via bash console sessions, so you can just go ahead and use it!

(historical answer follows for anyone curious / affected by a similar problem)

> PythonAnywhere admin here, we'll try and include mysqldump asap.
>
> In the meantime, maybe some kind of serialization could be the answer?
>
> If you're using Django for example, you could use its ORM to convert
>   each record to some kind of JSON or XML serialised representation, and
>   dump them to a text file...
>
> Django has an admin command you can use for that:
>
> ```
> python manage.py dumpdata my_app > my_app_dump.json
> ```
>
> more info here:
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model
>
> If you're not using django, maybe something like SQLAlchemy could
>   help?  there's a few pointers here:
>   [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json)
>
> Maybe we'll just hurry up and get mysqldump in!

Comment: Thank you. Would really appreciate if you can get mysqldump in soon. I am not using Django. This is not for a web app.

Comment: It works great. I am amazed by how promptly you installed it. Pythonanywhere team is awesome to work with.

Comment: Now if only we could get PostgreSQL installed...:)