# How to convert all Decimals in a Python data structure to string?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, decimal

I'm building a website using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) from which I use the jsonify method a lot to convert mostly dictionaries to Json.

The problem is now that I also use Decimals a lot, and unfortunately jsonify cannot handle Decimals:

```
jsonify({'a': Decimal('1')})
```

leads to:

```
=== (a long stacktrace preceding this) ===
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/json.py", line 83, in default
return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: Decimal('1') is not JSON serializable
```

So I wanted to wrap jsonify in a method like this:

```
def myOwnJsonify(item):
    if isinstance(item, Decimal):
        return flask.jsonify(str(item))
    else:
        return flask.jsonify(item)
```

unfortunately, this doesn't convert Decimals which reside within a dict or list.

How can I convert all Decimal numbers within a python data structure (be it a list, a dict, a tuple, etc.) into a string so that I can safely convert the datastructure into json?

Comment: Maybe not the best way but couldn't you subclass `Decimal` instead and override its `__repr__` method to get what you want?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can override the application's JSON encoder by setting the [`json_encoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder) attribute on your application instance:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(...)
app.json_encoder = MyJSONEncoder
```

Then you can sub-class Flask's [`JSONEncoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder) and override the [`default()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.JSONEncoder.default) method to provide support for additional types:

```
import decimal
import flask.json

class MyJSONEncoder(flask.json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
            # Convert decimal instances to strings.
            return str(obj)
        return super(MyJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

Comment: It's probably just a matter of different versions, but I had to do `app.data.json_encoder_class = MyJSONEncoder` to make it work.

Comment: @hlongmore I checked the latest version of Flask, 1.1.1, and it looks like it's still using the *json_encoder/decoder* attributes on the *Flask* class. I see no mention of *json_encoder_class* in the [Github repo](https://github.com/pallets/flask).

Comment: I hadn't checked my flask version; because of issues with some sub-package requirements that I don't have time to sort out right now (likely due to eve-sqlalchemy being very far behind eve), I had to pin eve to <0.8, which results in flask==0.12.