# SQLALchemy and Python - Getting the SQL result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using cloudkitty which is rating module in OpenStacks.

But here question is regarding the SQLAlchemy and Python.

I am new to SQLAlchemy.

I need to fetch some details from a table using a API call.

So I am creating a API call which is as follows:

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: token" http://128.0.0.1:8888/v1/report/invoice?invoice_id=7b73b9644e8242b3a740afc4659d9829
```

Which returned the data as follows:

```
"[<cloudkitty.storage.sqlalchemy.models.InvoiceDetails object at 0x7ff8b1dfe2d0>]"
```

Code which is returning the above result is as follows:

def get_invoice(self, tenant_id=None, invoice_id=None):

```
model = models.InvoiceDetails

session = db.get_session()
q = session.query(model)

if tenant_id:
        q = q.filter(model.tenant_id == tenant_id)
if invoice_id:
        q = q.filter(model.invoice_id == invoice_id)

print q
r = q.all()

return r
```

Need to find the way for Fetching the value instead of object.

Any help is appreciated.

Need to return it as values instead of object.

**Note:**

When I was trying to print the Query and executing the same in back-end it returns results correctly.(print q)

Answer (score 1):

`r = q.all()` returns raw SQLAlchemy results (iterable of instances). Python and SQLAlchemy do not have information how to serialize this for HTTP presentation. It simply calls Python string representation `__str__` function which gives the default Python debug output.

What you most likely want to have is [JSON](http://json.org/) presentation, as a common web de facto standard and platform neutral format, of SQLAlchemy data. [It is extensively covered in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json).