# creating a list of class objects

Tags: python, list, class, object

I am trying to create a list of python class objects.

Basically I am expecting for list which should be as follows:

```
[<Report {u'invoice_id': u'demo-1-2016-dummy', u'tenant_id': u'27724b57e3b744f89cbf1336da062b43'}>, <Report {u'invoice_id': u'demo-2-2016', u'tenant_id': u'27724b57e3b744f89cbf1336da062b43'}>, <Report {u'invoice_id': u'admin-2-2016', u'tenant_id': u'6cd02afa3f0f403489153c41e98d07bc'}>]
```

I have tried the following code for the same.

```
from cloudkittyclient.common import base
import json

class ReportResult(base.Resource):

    key = 'report'

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Report %s>" % self._info

class ReportManager(base.CrudManager):

    base_url = '/v1/report'
    resource_class = ReportResult
    key = "report"
    collection_key = "reports"

    # List the invoices, can accept all-tenants arg
    def list_invoice(self, all_tenants=None):
        url = self.base_url + "/list_invoice"
        filters = list()
        if all_tenants:
            filters.append("all_tenants=%s" % all_tenants)
        if filters:
            url += "?%s" % ('&'.join(filters))
        return self.client.get(url).json()
```

So here my requirement is that "return self.client.get(url).json()" should return the above mentioned List which consists of class objects.

But it is returning the results as follows:

```
[{u'invoice_id': u'demo-1-2016-dummy', u'tenant_id': u'27724b57e3b744f89cbf1336da062b43'}, {u'invoice_id': u'demo-2-2016', u'tenant_id': u'27724b57e3b744f89cbf1336da062b43'}, {u'invoice_id': u'admin-2-2016', u'tenant_id': u'6cd02afa3f0f403489153c41e98d07bc'}]
```

I know the fact that I am missing something right here.

As I am novice user in python I am unable to find that where I am going wrong.

Can anyone be able to assist me with getting the result I expected.

Comment: Please stop using `repr` strings as serialization. `return self.client.get(url).json()` is returning just that: a `list` of python `dict`ionaries that can be then serialized to JSON for transfer.

Comment: Hardly I need the list with class objects of the same. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLALchemy and Python - Getting the SQL result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407120/sqlalchemy-and-python-getting-the-sql-result)

Comment: Then don't call `.json()`? That `[<Report {...}>, ...]` is still just a helpful debug output of a list of `Report` instances. You seem to confuse it with something else.

Comment: This question seems to be about some deep internal stuff in a library rather than a general Python class, but it has no tags indicating what the library is (and several very uselessly broad tags like `object` and `class`). I strongly suggest getting rid of the general tags and adding something more specific (I have no idea what `cloudkitty` is, or I'd edit the tags in myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

```
return [self.resource_class(self, j, loaded=True)
        for j in self.client.get(url).json() if j]
```

---

You should not have to handle URL creation yourself. The `CrudManager` should take care of that for you, if you use the methods offered.

Try

```
report_manager.get(report_id=my_report_id)
```

where `my_report_id` is a variable containing an id, if you're trying to fetch a single report, instead of

```
report_manager.client.get(url).json()
```

Looking into [`cloudkittyclient.openstack.common.apiclient.base.BaseManager._get`](https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient/blob/master/cloudkittyclient/openstack/common/apiclient/base.py#L146) that `self.client.get(url).json()` is what it does internally, before it then deserializes the `JSON` to `self.resource_class` instance. You probably should not be doing that directly.

`cloudkittyclient.common.base.CrudManager` uses the `_get` internally and offers an override of [`get`](https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient/blob/master/cloudkittyclient/common/base.py#L105) that will handle `base_url` catenation etc for you.

Also it seems you should be using [`cloudkittyclient.common.base.CrudManager.findAll`](https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient/blob/master/cloudkittyclient/common/base.py#L122) or [`cloudkittyclient.common.base.CrudManager.list`](https://github.com/openstack/python-cloudkittyclient/blob/master/cloudkittyclient/openstack/common/apiclient/base.py#L346), since you have a method like `list_invoice`.

```
report_manager.findAll()
```

or

```
report_manager.findAll(all_tenants=all_tenants)
```

where `all_tenants` is a variable with what ever you would pass to your custom `list_invoice` method.

Finally, if `findAll` or `CrudManager.list` is really unsuitable to your needs, which seems to be the case since your collection url differs from the one in the class, you have to deserialize the results of `self.client.get(url).json()` yourself. So instead of returning that, do

```
return [self.resource_class(self, j, loaded=True)
        for j in self.client.get(url).json() if j]
```

which creates a list of instances of `self.resource_class` class (`ReportResult` here) from python `dict`ionaries that have been deserialized from a response of `JSON` data.

Consider overloading the `list` method of `CrudManager`, as it seems to be the way to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks , But it gives an error: TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Ah true, `get()` takes only kwargs. It accepts stuff like `base_url`, `'%s_id' % self.key` -> `report_id` etc.

Comment: @iamnewuser please try to use your ReportManager instance's `findAll` method.

Comment: This one: return [self.resource_class(self, j, loaded=True)
        for j in self.client.get(url).json() if j]

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain what it is happening here exactly.?

Comment: @iamnewuser edited a bit to clarify what that list comprehension does.