# connect SQLAlchemy ORM with the objects from sql core expression?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, object-relational-model

I have to use SQLalchemy Core expression to fetch objects because ORM can't do "update and returning". (the update in ORM doesn't has `returning`)

```
from sqlalchemy import update
class User(ORMBase): 
    ...
# pure sql expression, the object returned is not ORM object.
# the object is a RowProxy.
object = update(User)  \
    .values({'name': 'Wayne'})  \
    .where(User.id == subquery.as_scalar()) \
    .returning() \
    .fetchone()
```

When

```
db_session.add(object)
```

it report `UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy' is not mapped`.

How do I put that `RowProxy` object from sql expression into identity map of ORM
?

Comment: It seems like an oversight by `SQLAlchemy` that something like `update-returning`, which (typically) returns the whole table being updated, doesn't have a simple way to map back to objects. Unfortunate there's not a happier answer for this.

Comment: You *may* be able to get some mileage out of: `obj = User(**dict(object.items()))` but it doesn't appear to work in all instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple case:

Possible quick solution: construct the object from `kwargs` of your `RowProxy`, since those are object-like.

Given:

```
rowproxy = update(User)  \
    .values({'name': 'Wayne'})  \
    .where(User.id == subquery.as_scalar()) \
    .returning() \
    .fetchone()
```

We might be able to do:

```
user = User(**dict(rowproxy.items()))
```

`rowproxy.items()` returns `tuples` of `key-value` pairs; `dict(...)` converts the `tuples` into actual `key-value` pairs; and `User(...)` takes `kwargs` for the `model` attribute names.

### More difficult case:

But what if you have a `model` where one of the `attribute names` isn't quite the same as the SQL `table` `column name`? E.g. something like:

```
class User(ORMBase):
    # etc...
    user_id = Column(name='id', etc)
```

When we try to unpack our `rowproxy` into the `User` class, we'll likely get an error along the lines of: `TypeError: 'id' is an invalid keyword argument for User` (because it's expecting `user_id` instead).

Now it gets dirty: we should have lying around a `mapper` for how to get from the `table` attributes to the `model` attributes and vice versa:

```
kw_map = {a.key: a.class_attribute.name for a in User.__mapper__.attrs}
```

Here, `a.key` is the `model attribute` (and `kwarg`), and `a.class_attribute.name` is the `table attribute`. This gives us something like:

```
{
    "user_id": "id"
}
```

Well, we want to actually provide the values we got back from our `rowproxy`, which besides allowing object-like access also allows dict-like access:

```
kwargs = {a.key: rowproxy[a.class_attribute.name] for a in User.__mapper__.attrs}
```

And now we can do:

```
user = User(**kwargs)
```

#### Errata:

- you may want to `session.commit()` right after calling `update().returning()` to prevent long delays from your changes vs. when they get permanently stored in the database. No need to `session.add(user)` later - you already `updated()` and just need to `commit()` that transaction
- `object` is a keyword in Python, so try not to stomp on it; you could get some very bizarre behavior doing that; that's why I renamed to `rowproxy`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there is a straight-forward way to do what you're describing, which is essentially to build an ORM object that maps directly to an database entry but without performing the query through the ORM.

My intuition is that the naive approach (just build init the ORM object with the values in the database) would just create another row with the same values (or fail to because of uniqueness constraints).

The more standard way to do what you are asking would be to query the row through the ORM *first* and then update the database from that ORM object.

```
user = User.query.filter(User.user_attribute == 'foo').one()
user.some_value = 'bar'
session.add(user)
session.commit()
```

I'm not sure if you have some constraint on your end that prevents you from using that pattern though. The documentation works through similar [examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/tutorial.html#adding-and-updating-objects)