# Read entire database with sqlalchemy and dump as JSON

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

Django has the convenience `manage.py` command `dumpdata` [which can be configured to dump an entire database as `JSON`](https://coderwall.com/p/mvsoyg/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata).

At present I am confined to using `sqlalchemy` and I'd like to do the same thing:

Take as input **a connection string** like `'mysql+pymysql://user:pwd@localhost:3306/'` and **get the contents of the database as `JSON`** (I don't require all the meta info that Django provides, but I won't mind).

I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json) elaborating how to dump SQLAlchemy objects to JSON and [this from the sqlalchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) outlining how to get all tablenames from a database:

```
meta = MetaData()
input_db = f'sqlite:///tmpsqlite'
engine = create_engine(input_db)
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
print(meta.tables)
```

How do I retrieve all of the content of these tables and then convert them to `JSON`? Is there a built-in command in `sqlalchemy` similar to django's dumpdata functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaving my solution here for posterity:

```
import json

def dump_sqlalchemy(output_connection_string,output_schema):
    """ Returns the entire content of a database as lists of dicts"""
    engine = create_engine(f'{output_connection_string}{output_schema}')
    meta = MetaData()
    meta.reflect(bind=engine)  # http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/reflection.html
    result = {}
    for table in meta.sorted_tables:
        result[table.name] = [dict(row) for row in engine.execute(table.select())]
    return json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Note that the `zip(...)` is redundant. A [`RowProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.RowProxy) is a mapping in its own right and you can simply pass it to `dict()` constructor: `dict(row)`.

Comment: Which is what you get, if you pass `dict()` a row proxy object.

Comment: The imports required for sqlalchemy are `from sqlalchemy import create_engine; from sqlalchemy.schema import MetaData`

Comment: Is this generating one json file for a table? isn't could this break with a low memory limit or a huge amount of data per table?

Comment: @Gabor this is one json (dictionary and after json.dumps(...)) with all the tables as keys and values as their content. Indeed if the table is too large you could run out of memory.