# How to deserialize an object that has been converted to string type with bytes syntax

Tags: python, jquery, flask, sqlalchemy, deserialization

**Context**

I have a Flask app that uses sqlalchemy to query a database and serialize the resulting sqlalchemy object.  After the template is rendered, I want to pass the serialized object to `/_background_process` route using a jQuery callback function on keyup (see jQuery and route below).

The serialized object is passed in the callback function via an argument named `callbackarg` using the jinja2 `"{{ ... }}"` delimiter.  The quotation marks are required else a SyntaxError will occur because `serializedobj` is a bytes object including invalid tokens like `&` (such as in `b&#39;\x80\x04\x95...`)

**Where I'm stuck**

When the serialized object is retrieved via `request.args.get('callbackarg')` in the `/_background_process` route, it is of string type with bytes syntax (versus bytes type) and has lost the decode attribute.  This is a problem because the argument must be a bytes object to deserialize with the `loads` method of `sqlalchemy.ext.serializer`

**Some of the things I've tried**

I've tried using other serializer libraries.  Both `flask.jsonify` and `json.dumps` fail because one of the child objects in the sqlalchemy object "is not JSON serializable".  `pickle.dumps` gives an identical result to `dumps` method of `sqlalchemy.ext.serializer`.  The approach described in this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json) also fails because of elements that are not JSON serializable.

**Summarizing the question**

Is there a way to deserialize `retrievedobj` in the `/_background_process` route after it has been serialized and passed as a string with bytes syntax in a callback function?  If there is no way, please would you weigh in on the related question I asked on November 1 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094259/unable-to-pass-sqlalchemy-list-object-in-a-jquery-callback-function)?  Thanks!

**jQuery in Flask template**

```
<script type=application/javascript>
$(function() {
    $('#process_input').on('keyup', function() {
    $.getJSON('/_background_process', {
        userinput: $('input[name="userinput"]').val(),
        callbackarg: {{ serializedobj }}
    }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

**App route**

```
@app.route('/_background_process')
def _background_process():
    retrievedobj = request.args.get('callbackarg')
    ...
```

**Footnote**
This is a different question than the one I asked Nov 1 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094259/unable-to-pass-sqlalchemy-list-object-in-a-jquery-callback-function) because, whereas that question was about passing an object of type `sqlalchemy`, this question is strictly about passing a serialized object.

Comment: You really should stop and think for a moment at this point. First off, reading https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/serializer.html it seems it isn't meant for serializing model objects. You're saying that some child object in your model object is not JSON serializable. In that case write an adapter/converter that makes it so. Don't try and use string representations of Python objects as "serialization". Also, pickle isn't safe against malicious data, so in general it might not be a good idea to accept pickled data in an endpoint as input.

Comment: you almost certainly don't want to do this.  anything coming from the browser should be treated as untrusted.  https://jwt.io/ might help, but you should probably just be saving the relevant state into a database