# Why is "Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable" - when using marshmallow with SQLAlchemy automap?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Using `automap_base` from `sqlalchemy.ext.automap` to map my tables.
Not able to `shema.dumps(result)`;

getting

```py
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable
```

Tried using JSON custom decoders, but no use.

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

engine = db.engine
session = Session(engine)

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

MyTable = Base.classes.my_table

class MyTableSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = MyTable

@app.route("/")
def api():
    all_rows = session.query(MyTable).all()
    schema = MyTableSchema(many=True)
    response = schema.dumps(all_rows)

    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I believe the docs cover this https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html?highlight=function#marshmallow.fields.Decimal

Comment: Nope, it does not cover, the whole point of `automapping` is, it does not need `marshmallow.fields.*` right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with automapping (though this is a sqlalchemy thing rather than marshmallow thing) but I'm guessing it defines `MyTable` along with the sqlalchemy column types and one of these is of type `Decimal`. You can override marshmallow column types by expicitly putting the columns above `class Meta:` say `ProblemField = ma.fields.Decimal(as_string=True)`. I'll leave it to others to confirm/contradict if this is the right approach.

Comment: this article is useful for the error in general i hope it helps https://medium.com/@erdoganyesil/typeerror-object-of-type-is-not-json-serializable-6230ccc74975

Answer (score 4):

An easy workaround to `transform` an `SQLAlchemy result` object in `JSON` is using `simplejson`.

You just need to import it (`import simplejson`) and it works.

Using your example:

```
import simplejson
...
@app.route("/")
def api():
    all_rows = session.query(MyTable).all()
    response = simplejson.dumps(all_rows)
```

Comment: As with every other attempt I get `TypeError: Object of type BaseQuery is not JSON serializable` It's really suprising to me that this is just so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Add .data to response like below

```
def api():
    all_rows = session.query(MyTable).all()
    schema = MyTableSchema(many=True)
    response = schema.dumps(all_rows)

    return response.data
```