# TypeError: Object of type is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, flask, serialization, flask-restful

I'm wrote `rest` on the Flask using `flask-marshmallow`

**models.py**

```
class Application(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'applications'

    id = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    versions = db.relationship('Version', backref='application', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<application {}>'.format(self.name)


class Version(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'versions'

    id = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    file = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    application_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('applications.id'))
```

**shemas.py**

```
class ApplicationDetailSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'versions')
```

**routes.py**

```
@bp.route("/<id>")
def application_detail(id):
    application = Application.query.get(id)
    result = application_detail_schema.dump(application)
    return jsonify(result)
```

> TypeError: Object of type 'Version' is not JSON serializable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: @alexdefelipe Dont't work. It's a problem with `flask`

Comment: If you're using sql-alchemy, check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180522/3559330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `ModelSchema` instead of `Schema`.

```
class ApplicationDetailSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'versions')
```

`ModelSchema` dumps the related foreign key objects as a list of id(s) by default which is JSON serializable.

Comment: `'Marshmallow' object has no attribute 'ModelSchema'`

Comment: Do you have `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` installed?

Answer (score 6):

In order to use `jsonify()` you have to make serializable the class you need to jsonify. Add to that class a function similar to the following:

```
class Version(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'versions'

    id = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    file = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    application_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('applications.id'))

    def serialize(self):
        return {"id": self.id,
                "file": self.file,
                "application_id": self.application_id}
```

And then jsonify de serializaed version of the object, and not the objetc itself:

```
jsonify(result.serialize())
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use @dataclass decorator

on version 3.7+, u can use the **dataclass** decorator:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Application(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'applications'

    id = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())
    versions = db.relationship('Version', backref='application', lazy=True)
```

then, **jsonify** works fine.

Comment: Word of caution. I added the @dataclass decorator and then I got all nulls for the attributes. I had to remove the _init_ method and replace with the list of class attributes via the documentation. So yes works but know that to convert your class to a dataclass there is a little more work than just adding the decorator. But yes it now works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This method work for me

```
class User(db.Model, Timestamp):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable= False)
   email = db.Column(db.String(40), unique = True, nullable= False)

   def toDict(self):
       return dict(id=self.id, name=self.id email=self.email)
```

and

```
return jsonify([s.toDict() for s in admins])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

Try with json.dumps() and json.loads()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html