# SQLAlchemy & SQLAlchemySchema GET return jsonified data is empty dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

This is my Model:

```
class Todo(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "todos"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)


class TodoSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
```

This is my route

```
@app.route("/data", methods=["GET"])
def data():
    data = Todo.query.all()
    print(len(data)) #28
    print(data) #[<Todo 1>, <Todo 2>, <Todo 3>, <Todo 4>, <Todo 5>, <Todo 6>, <Todo 7>, <Todo 8>, <Todo 9>, <Todo 10>, <Todo 11>, <Todo 12>, <Todo 13>, <Todo 14>, <Todo 15>, <Todo 16>, <Todo 17>, <Todo 18>, <Todo 19>, <Todo 20>, <Todo 21>, <Todo 22>, <Todo 23>, <Todo 24>, <Todo 25>, <Todo 26>, <Todo 27>, <Todo 28>]
    todo_schema = TodoSchema()
    output = todo_schema.dump(data)
    print(output) # {}
    return output
```

When I do a loop it looks like this:

```
for item in data:
   print(item.description)

walk the dog
buy groceries
....
```

You can see the output of the `print` statements behind it in the comments.
So what I want is the make a JSON Object from the data object which I can return. What is the reason output results in an empty dictionary? Is there a simple solution like

```
data = Todo.query.all()
return jsonify({data})
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884806/9203110

Comment: I took my implementation from there, but I does not help me, since the example does not return an empty dictionary. This is what I do not understand.

Comment: You don't need to use `output` or `todo_schema` - you have the results in `data` - just convert it to json via the column names as shown in that link.

Answer (score 0):

There's one problem with your code. You are fetching all the Todos from the database with

```
Todo.query.all()
```

But when you are instantiating your Schema, you didn't specified **many** parameter. Change your Schema instantiation to

```
todo_schema = TodoSchema(many=True)
```

Quoting the documentation

> **many** – Should be set to **True** if obj is a collection so that the object will be serialized to a list.

For your reference go to https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema and head to the parameters of **marshmallow.Schema** class

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments there's another problem that now it returns a list of empty dictionaries. For that here's a reference link
https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html

Try using **ModelSchema** instead of **SQLAlchemySchema**.

Comment: A little bit better, but now I get a list with many empty dicionaries. The data is still getting lost.

Comment: I'm not sure but try adding field to Meta class. Something like fields = ("id", "description")

Comment: Silly mistake here. Try using ModelSchema instead of SQLAlchemySchema

Comment: ModelSchema seems to be no more in the package

Comment: Make sure you are using marshmallow-sqlalchemy(https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and not importing from marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

@targhs was spot on. I'll add what ultimately got me past the empty list problem as applicable to your code:

```
output = todo_schema.dump(data, many=True)
return todo_schema.jsonify(data, many=True)
```

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do. However, you can turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

import **field_for** from **marshmallow_sqlalchemy** and add this in to the class TodoSchema

```
class TodoSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
 id = field_for(Todo, 'id', dump_only=True) #update this
 description = field_for(Todo, 'description', dump_only=True) #update this

class Meta:
    model = Todo
```