# Return JSON array of objects in Flask

Tags: json, rest, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, jsonify

I am working on a simple CRUD application and I can't return an array of objects in Flask.

My db Model is like this:

```
class QrRecord(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.String(256), primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
  qrType = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  count = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

  def toJson(self):
    return jsonify(
      {
        "id": self.id,
        "name": self.name,
        "date": self.date,
        "qrType": self.qrType,
        "count": self.count
      }
    )
```

And I am trying to return it like so:

```
@app.route("/qr", methods=["GET"])
def qr_get():
  tasks: list = QrRecord.query.order_by(QrRecord.date).all()
  return jsonify(tasks)
```

The error I get is:

```
<title>TypeError: Object of type type is not JSON serializable
  // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
```

When I am returning one single object as return `return tasks[0].toJson()`, it works just fine. The same when I would return an array of anything else, just like `return jsonify([1, 2, 3])`.

Would anybody know how to return the array of QrRecords? I feel like I have tried every solution already.

Comment: `return jsonify(tasks)`

Comment: @python_user That was a typo that I fixed, but I am still getting the same response, but with "Object of type Response" instead of "Object of type type". I also tried it as `return jsonify([task.toJson() for task in tasks]), 200`, but still the same.

Comment: What's `toJson`? How would `jsonify` know to call it?

Comment: @ggorlen That is a method I defined in the QrRecord class.

Comment: I can see that, but based on what documentation did you pick the name? How would `jsonify` know to call it? Just because you happen to have the word "json" in it doesn't mean `jsonify` knows anything about it. You could have called the method `asdashdd_foo` and you'd have the same result, no?

Comment: @ggorlen Well, that's the thing. If I were to write `return jsonify({"id": tasks[0], ...})` it would work, but I do not want to loop through all the items like that (https://pastebin.com/jdRvquQQ - this is working). `toJson()` is just a name I came up for a method that I used in the snippet so that I could show that for one item, but not for more items in a list.

Comment: Yes, `jsonify` knows what to do with nested primitive structures (lists and dicts) but not with your model class. I'd make it an `@dataclass` (see [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57732785/6243352)), or use `jsonify([x.toJson() for x in tasks])` and remove `jsonify()` from the `toJson` method so it just returns a dict.

Comment: I think you can change the `toJson()` function to just return the dict (without calling `jsonify()`) and then change the `qr_get()` function to `return jsonify([task.toJson() for task in tasks]), 200`. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Both of your solutions worked for me, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has already been more or less answered to here: [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json/57732785#57732785)

Using `@dataclass` together with statically typed params helped:

```
@dataclass
class QrRecord(db.Model):
  id: str = db.Column(db.String(256), primary_key=True)
  name: str = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  date: datetime = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
  qrType: str = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  count: int = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

@app.route("/qr", methods=["GET"])
def qr_get():
  tasks: list = QrRecord.query.order_by(QrRecord.date).all()
  return jsonify(tasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `tasks` is a list of db objects, which (as the error says) is not JSON serializable. You can solve this by iterating over each object in your query, getting it's `toJson()` return value, then adding it to the list. Then, you should be able to simply return the list.

```py
@app.route("/qr", methods=["GET"])
def qr_get():
  tasks = []
  for record in QrRecord.query.order_by(QrRecord.date).all():
    tasks.append(record.toJson())
  return tasks
```