# sqlalchemy model to json

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I am making an API for communication between front and back ends, on the server side i have python getting sqlalchemy models to send them back, the problem is i can't find a way to convert them to JSON so i can send them back.

I did see [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json) but this thread is 12 years old. I have try to output the model as dictionary as suggested with this;

```
class User:
   def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}
```

But my model is an inherited one and it only output the columns (fields) directly own by the model, it doesn't output the inherited columns which i need.

How can i get i read an sqlalchemy model object and output it as JSON with all it's inherited fields?

Comment: Does `self.__mapper__.columns` work better?

Comment: Yes, it does what i was looking for and gives me all the inherited fields. Thanks! Although now i wonder if this is the right method seeing the answer of Yurii.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do that:

**1) using [SQLAlchemy-serializer mixin](https://github.com/n0nSmoker/SQLAlchemy-serializer)**

```
import json
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_serializer import SerializerMixin

class Base(DeclarativeBase, SerializerMixin):
    pass

class Project(Base):
     __tablename__="projects"
     id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
     name: Mapped[str]
     owner_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__="users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    projects: Mapped[list[Project]] = relationship(backref="owner")
    serialize_rules = ('-projects.owner',)  # Specify where to stop recursion


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


with session_maker() as session:
    user = User(name="User1")

    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 1"))
    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 2"))

    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(user)

    print(json.dumps(user.to_dict()))
```

Output:

```
{"id": 1, "projects": [{"id": 1, "name": "Project 1", "owner_id": 1}, {"id": 2, "name": "Project 2", "owner_id": 1}], "name": "User1"}
```

**2) Using Pydantic**

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, sessionmaker
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# SQLAlchemy models
class Project(Base):
     __tablename__="projects"
     id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
     name: Mapped[str]
     owner_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__="users"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    projects: Mapped[list[Project]] = relationship(backref="owner")


# Pydantic models
class ProjectScheme(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    id: int
    name: str

class UserScheme(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    id: int
    name: str
    projects: list[ProjectScheme]


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with session_maker() as session:
    user = User(name="User1")

    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 1"))
    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 2"))

    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(user)

    user_dict = UserScheme.model_validate(user).model_dump_json()

    print(user_dict)
```

Output:

```
{"id":1,"name":"User1","projects":[{"name":"Project 1","id":1},{"name":"Project 2","id":2}]}
```

**3) Using [SQLModel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/)**

With SQLModel you can reduce redundancy in your models:

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Relationship


class ProjectBase(SQLModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str

class Project(ProjectBase, table=True):
    __tablename__="projects"
    owner_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="users.id")
    owner: "User" = Relationship(back_populates="projects")


class UserBase(SQLModel):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str


class User(UserBase, table=True):
    __tablename__="users"
    projects: list[Project] = Relationship(back_populates="owner")

class UserOutput(UserBase):
    projects: list[ProjectBase] = []


engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

with session_maker() as session:
    user = User(name="User1")

    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 1"))
    user.projects.append(Project(name="Project 2"))

    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(user)

    print(UserOutput.model_validate(user).model_dump_json())
```

Output:

```
{"id":1,"name":"User1","projects":[{"name":"Project 1","id":1},{"name":"Project 2","id":2}]}
```

Comment: Are all these 3 solutions compatible with dates?

Comment: I'm not sure. Can you try and post results?