# Dumping SQLAlchemy output to JSON

Tags: python

I have written a small python script that uses SQLAlchemy to read all records of the db. Here is some of the code

```
Base=declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
cess=Session()

class Test(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'test'
     my_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String)
     def __init__(self, id, name):
         self.my_id = id
         self.name = name
     def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%d','%s')>" % (self.id, self.name)



query= cess.query(Test.my_id, Test.name).order_by(Test.my_id).all()
```

Now the query object i want to convert to a json string. How can i do this ? using json.dumps(query) throws an exception ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize SqlAlchemy result to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022066/how-to-serialize-sqlalchemy-result-to-json)

Answer (score 4):

[json.dumps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) will convert object according to its [conversion table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

Since you have rows of type `Test`, these cannot be directly serialized.  Probably the quickest approach is to convert each returned row to a Python `dict` and then pass this through to `json.dumps`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict) describes how you might go about converting a table row to a dict.

Or, perhaps the [_asdict()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) method from row object can be utilised directly.

```
query = cess.query(Test.my_id, Test.name).order_by(Test.my_id).all()

json.dumps([ row._asdict() for row in query ])
```

An alternative might be to access the `__dict__` attribute directly on each row, although you should check the output to ensure that there are no internal state variables in `row.__dict__`.

```
query = cess.query(Test.my_id, Test.name).order_by(Test.my_id).all()

json.dumps([ row.__dict__ for row in query ])
```

Comment: Could you please show __dict__ method. I am really new to python ?

Comment: @BadLuckBrian Answer edited.  Sorry, I had the wrong hyperlink to the SO answer.

Comment: print json.dumps([ row2dict(row) for row in query.all() ])
  File "alc-test.py", line 28, in row2dict
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
AttributeError: 'KeyedTuple' object has no attribute '__table__'

Comment: @BadLuckBrian I haven't got access to a machine to test this at present, but perhaps you can use _asdict() as per the latest edit?  Basically, the idea is for you to convert a row to dictionary which can then be understood by `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 2):

How I did it:

```
fe = SomeClass.query.get(int(1))
fe_dict = fe.__dict__
del fe_dict['_sa_instance_state']
return flask.jsonify(fe_dict)
```

Basically, given the object you've retrieved, grab the dict for the class instance, remove the sqlalchemy object that can't be json serialized and convert to json. I'm using flask to do this but I think json.dumps() would work the same.