# How to get column and values dictionary in SQLAlchemy model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table:

```
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(255))
    email = Column(String(255))
```

Is it possible to get a dictionary that for empty record will return something like:

```
{'id': None, 'username': None, 'email': None}
```

And if I do:

```
user = User()
user.username = "testuser"
user.email = "test@example.com"
```

I want to be able to get the dictionary with the corresponding values. Of course if I save the record I'd expect it to have the `id` there as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of `user.__table__.columns`:

```
def get_model_dict(model):
    return dict((column.name, getattr(model, column.name)) 
                for column in model.__table__.columns)
```

Usage:

```
user = User()
get_model_dict(user)
```

There are also other options at:

- [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios, column name is fit for them. 
But maybe you write the code like follows:

```
class UserModel(BaseModel):
    user_id = Column("user_id", INT, primary_key=True)
    email = Column("user_email", STRING)
```

the column.name "user_email" while the field name is "email",
the column.name could not work well as before.

There is a another trick by using Python metaclass, the sample code:

[sqlalchemy_base_model.py](https://gist.github.com/kaka19ace/760380b8c267a3fc288c)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method which is inspired by the answer [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) gave.

```
def get_model_dict(model, row):
    if isinstance(row, model):
        columns = [x.name for x in list(model.__table__.columns)]
        return {x: getattr(row, x) for x in columns}
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"The provided row is not of type {model.__table__.name.title()}")
```

Now all you have to do is pass the model and the row of the same models to get the dictionary representation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

this is how.

```
getattr(User, 'id')
```