# python Storm ORM : how to make resultset to be dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-storm

I want to make result to be dict:

```
gyms = store.find(Gym)
for g in gyms:
    print dict(g)
```

It's wrong with it , but how could I make the result to be dict ?

Now I get dict with a function:

```
class Gym(object):

    def get_dict(self):
    return dict(id   = self.id,
                name = self.name,
                addr = self.addr,
                create_time = str(self.create_time))
```

but I have to define get_dict() to every class,I can't bare with it.

How could I get dict convenient ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Storm, but you can do this in SQLAlchemy like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict .

Comment: BTW, Storm is an old and inactive library, I suggest you to use SQLAlchemy or Peewee instead.

Comment: Is this question tagged correctly? Apache Storm is a distributed stream processing system and no "old and inactive library" for Python.

Comment: We are talking about python ORM Storm --- https://storm.canonical.com

Comment: I don't like SQLAlchemy,it's so complex. I love storm because it simple ,and you can code beautiful. peewee is ugly because of  'class Meta'.