# Flask Alchemy with Marshmallow returns empty JSON

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am trying to return a json data after query from my database using Flask Alchemy, and Flask Marshmallow

However, my code somehow always returns empty JSON data.

Here's my code :

My View :

```
@app.route('/customer/', methods=['GET'])
def get_customer():
  customers = models.Customer.query.all()
  #c = models.Customer.query.get(1) # Get Customer with an ID of 1

  customers_schema = CustomerSchema()

  print customers_schema.dump(customers).data
  payload = customers_schema.dump(customers).data
  resp = Response(response=payload, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
  return(resp)
```

My Models :

```
class Customer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    address = db.relationship('Address', backref='customer', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Customer %r>' % (self.nickname)
```

My Schema :

```
class CustomerSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

This is the result as seen from the console :

```
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 817-774-044
{}
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2016 09:37:59] "GET /customer/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{}
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2016 09:41:27] "GET /customer/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Is there anything that i miss ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 8):

In CustomerSchema you should pass the parameter as many=True, as you expect a list, such as:
customers_schema = CustomerSchema(many=True)

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add something to the answers above.

In Marshmallow 3.x, the parameter `strict` has been removed as schemas are always strict.

An empty JSON object as result may be caused by different cases, for instance I have once mistaken "=" with ":" in the schema which results in a `[ Unknown field. ]` on dumps and an empty JSON Object as result.

In order to debug in Marshmallow 3.x you may use `Schema.validate` which returns a dictionary of validation errors :

```
  customers_schema = CustomerSchema()

  print(customers_schema.validate(customers))
```

I hope this may help some people in the future

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I was going crazy over the [ Unknown field ] error.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting some error during serialization and you just ignore it. Try instantiating you schema with `strict=True` to see what errors are there:

`customers_schema = CustomerSchema(strict=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that if you try to validate a database response from `.query()` is not an orm-mapped object and is rather converted to a dictionary, as described here: [How to convert SQLAlchemy row object to a Python dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/how-to-convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-a-python-dict)
in the `row2dict` code sample.