# Flask: missing prefix when select with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I was creating an API using Flask and MySQLdb to query data but was advice to use sqlalchemy due to **connection pooling**. This will be better for my site if high traffic occurred as I do not need to do hard open and close database connection

However, when I transform the working code to sqlalchemy, it does not getting the prefix

```
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine

    @app.route('/KLSE/search', methods=['GET'])
    def KLSEsearch():
        engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://xxx:xxx@zzz.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/zzz$default')
        conn = engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        name = request.args.get('name',default='',type=str)
        volumeMin = request.args.get('volumeMin',default=0,type=float)
        volumeMax = request.args.get('volumeMax',default=0,type=float)
        query = """ SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE (Stock LIKE %s or Name LIKE %s or Stockcode LIKE %s)
                            AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF (%s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s))) """
        input = (name+"%",name+"%",name+"%",volumeMin,volumeMin,volumeMax,volumeMax)
    try:
        cur.execute(query,(input))
        h = cur.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
      return jsonify({'Stock': h})
```

Result:

```
{
  "Stock": [
    [
      11,
      "PRESTAR",
      "PRESTAR RESOURCES BERHAD [S]",
      23.8,
    ],
```

What I get from previous code with MySQLdb :

```
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template  
    import MySQLdb
    import MySQLdb.cursors

    @app.route('/KLSE/search', methods=['GET'])
    def KLSEsearch():
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com',user='zzz',passwd='xxx',db='zzz$default',cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        curs = db.cursor()
        name = request.args.get('name',default='',type=str)
        volumeMin = request.args.get('volumeMin',default=0,type=float)
        volumeMax = request.args.get('volumeMax',default=0,type=float)
        query = """ SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE (Stock LIKE %s or Name LIKE %s or Stockcode LIKE %s)
                            AND (Volume_changes_pc BETWEEN (IF (%s='_',-5000,%s)) AND (IF(%s='_',5000,%s))) """
        input = (name+"%",name+"%",name+"%",volumeMin,volumeMin,volumeMax,volumeMax)
    try:
        curs.execute(query,(input))
        h = curs.fetchall()
    except Exception:
        return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
    finally:
        curs.close()
        db.close()
      return jsonify({'Stock': h})
```

Result that require and show prefix:

```
{
  "Stock": [
    {
      "Stock": "PRESTAR",
      "Stockcode": "11",
      "Change_pc": 2.604,
      "Name": "PRESTAR RESOURCES BERHAD [S]",
    },
```

**In the code with sqlalchemy, I do not use cursor close and db close**, as sqlalchemy engine will handle the connection pooling, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that cursor object being serialized by `jsonify({'Stock': h})` is different for the SQLAlchemy and MySQLdb cursors.

All the data is [still there](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy) and can be accessed in multiple ways, so you just have to build a dictionary out of the SQLAlchemy cursor and then jsonify that.

So something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960546/1216837) should work (see link for other examples):

```
def row2dict(row):
    d = {}
    for column in row.__table__.columns:
        d[column.name] = str(getattr(row, column.name))
    return d
```

I don' think this has anything to do with connection pooling though.

Comment: I use sqlalchemy core because it can handle connection pooling. however, is my code is good for high traffic or still sqlalchemy ORM is preferred?

Comment: So you are asking two different questions, the first is after how to return your query results as a dictionary instead of a list. The second is about the performance of collection pooling in SQLAlchemy Core vs ORM. Is that correct?