# SQLAlchemy: Map column name to value automatically

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

## Background

When I want to create a dictionary to map the column name to values in a result, I need to list out each column individually

```
    result = self.session.query(Project)\
                .join(Deadline)\
                .values(Project.project_id, Project.project_name,
                    Project.project_root, Deadline.deadline_time)

    output = []
    for row in result:
        r = {}
        r['project_id'] = row.project_id
        r['project_name'] = row.project_name
        r['project_root'] = row.project_root
        r['deadline_time'] = row.deadline_time
        output.append(r)

    return output
```

The Models are ORM-mapped, and **not** SQLAlchemy core.

```
class Deadline(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'deadline'

    deadline_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    deadline_time = Column(String, nullable = False)


class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    project_id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    project_name = Column(String, nullable = False)
    project_root = Column(String, nullable = False)
    deadline_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("deadline.deadline_id"), nullable=False)
    deadline = relationship("Deadline", primaryjoin = "Project.deadline_id == Deadline.deadline_id", backref=backref("project", uselist=False))
```

---

## Question

This is not efficient for a table with many columns, nor can I re-use the same code for other tables.

I tried the following but could not get the column name

```
    column_names = [c["name"] for c in result.column_descriptions]
    return [dict(zip(column_names, row)) for row in result.all()]
    result.__table__.columns.keys()
```

## Edit 1

There are a few similar questions about [converting SQLAlchemy result into dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict). As per the code above, `result.__table__.columns.keys()` does not work for ORM-mapped models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row is SQLAlchemy [KeyedTuple](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple). Since 0.8 KeyedTuples have [`_asdict()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) method - you can simply use:

```
output = []

for row in result:
    output.append(row._asdict())
```

PS. You do not have to specify such a trivial `primaryjoin` in deadline relationship. SQLAlchemy will determine foreign keys on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use a dictionary comprehension:

```
r = {k: row[k] for k in row}
```

To include it with the output in a list comprehension:

```
output = [{k: row[k] for k in row} for row in result]
```

Instead of repeating the column name in each row JSON style, you may just want to append values to a list.

Answer (score 0):

[krassowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6646912/krassowski)'s [answer is exactly what I need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45702159/399759). For succinctness, I apply `_asdict()` as a lambda function.

```
result = self.session.query(Project)\
                .join(Deadline)\
                .values(Project.project_id, Project.project_name,
                    Project.project_root, Deadline.deadline_time)
map(lambda x: x._asdict(), result)
```