# SQLAlchemy RowProxy to dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I convert a sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy to a dictionary?

```
row = db.engine.execute(sql, id=id).fetchone()
```

Tried using this from SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350445/506565):

```
for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs:
    model_col = getattr(obj, c.key)
    model_dict[c.key] = model_col
```

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.result.RowProxy'>
```

Comment: You're looking at the wrong answer (of the many). Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958228/2681632. The answer you tried is for entities, or in other words model objects.

Comment: Also in some situations you might not even need the conversion. `RowProxy` objects are mappings on their own already.