# sqlalchemy showing complete row (all columns) from a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to log a complete row from a sqlalchemy query (ORM), when a specific bug appears (in my example this is when multiple rows where found, but this has nothing to do with the question).
At the moment i adress every column like this.

```
try:          
    result = query.one_or_none()
except MultipleResultsFound:
    self.logger.info('MultipleResultsFound!!')
    for row in query.all():
        self.logger.info('column1:{}, column2:{}, column3:{}'.
                          format(row.column1, row.column2, row.column3))
```

But there must be a better way without adressing every column to show every column in the log.
How can i display all columns from a row with one simple command ?

Comment: Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)?

Comment: Yes but all these solutions do not work, i always get an attribute error if the query is like this: query(func.max(...))

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) method

Also note you can use .label to naming your func in query.

e.g. `db.session.query(func.sum(SomeModel.something).label('total'))`

```
for row in query.all():
  print(row._asdict())
```