# Change the format of the returned data when selecting records. Flask

Tags: python, flask

In my flask application, in routes.py I get entries with specific fields of the `Location` model:

```
...
location = db.session.query(Location.id, Location.name,Location.code, Location.id_parent).all()
newLocat = list( location)
print(str(newLocat))
...
```

The format of the returned data is as follows:

```
[(1, 'Test1', 101, 0), (2, 'Test2', 202, 1)]
```

How to make the returned data format look like this?

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'Test1','code':101, 'id_parent': '0'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'Test2','code':202, 'id_parent': '1'}]
```

Comment: Why are you printing it as `str`?

Comment: What is `db.session` ? SQLAlchemy ? If yes, you may want to check SQLAlchemy's doc.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Yes, db.session is SQLAlchemy. Where can I see in the documentation the format of the returned data?

Comment: @Ambasador SQLAlchemy is a rather complex lib and I don't have much experience with it so I can't answer, but according to the first answer (NOT the accepted one) in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict), `[dict(row) for row in locations)]` should work. This being said, if you're using SQLAlchemy you'd better take some time reading the doc...

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code, here samp can be your return value.

```
final = []
for i in samp:
    row = {}
    row['id'] = i[0]
    row['name'] = i[1]
    row['code'] = i[2]
    row['id_parent'] = i[3]
    final.append(row)
print(final)
```

Comment: Since almost all db-api compliant connectors have a `DictCursor`, there's certainly a much better way.

Comment: @Gaurang Patel How can you get the required data format when sampling from the database without using cycles?

Comment: @Ambasador you can use this maybe print(json.dumps(response))