# How to convert a SQL Alchemy ORM to a dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to convert my SQL Alchemy to a basic dict.

For this case, I'm trying to use the `__dict__` builtin function.

But the behavior is quite strange.

Here is my function:

```
def trial_to_dict(sa_trial_instance):
    """"Convert a SQL Alchemy instance to a JSON dict
    params:
        sa_trial_instance (dict): SQL Alchemy instance
    returns:
        dict: JSON
    """

    temp_dict = sa_trial_instance.__dict__

    return {
        "ct_id": temp_dict["ct_id"],
        "study_type": temp_dict["study_type"],
        "phase": temp_dict["phase"]
    }
```

`sa_trial_instance` is defined, and it's a Sql Alchemy instance
[image: sa_trial_instance]

But `temp_dict` isn't the result I'm expecting :
[image: temp_dict]

Obvioulsy, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'ct_id'
```

Is anyone has an explanation about this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350445/137650 for a possible utility function to do the conversion for you

Comment: `'ct_id'` isn't even in your screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert sqlalchemy row object to python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-python-dict)