# about sqlalchemy how to output dict problem

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
nodes = db.query(A.id, B.name,C.name,D.name).outerjoin(B,C,D).filter(A.id==node_id).all()
for item in nodes:
   print(item)
```

> output is `<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>` (3, 'this is name', None, None)

i want ouput dict like this `{'id':3,'B.name':'this is name'...}`

What should I do?

Which good brother can help me?

> That's what I'm doing now
>
> I believe there will be a good brother and a better way

```
for item in nodes:
    print(dict(zip(['id','A.name','B.name','C.name'],item)))
```

Comment: From the linked duplicate, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311205/5320906) is the most modern way - requires 1.4/2.0 style usage.  Otherwise [_asdict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21029850/5320906) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Doing some quick searches suggests that you could use `dict(item)` to convert a `Row` into a dictionary.

I'm not a brother, though. :)

Comment: sry It won't work like this