# From dataclass "[x(id=1, c=1), x(id=2, c=4), x(...)...]" to Json/dict? | Serialize SQLAlchemy Result to Json / Struggling with output format

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, serialization, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to retrieve all records in a sqlite3 database via sqlalchemy.
Where I struggle is the output format, namely turning into a valid json format.

There are quite a few tutorials how to do it, and the most relevant I believe is this one: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57732785/1874025)

Having followed this approach (after trying many others, incl. pydantic), I managed to retrieve the data; now I'm down to putting it into the right format, and here's where I got stuck.

I feel I'm overlooking at tiny detail; any pointers would be appreciated.

I'm pretty sure I could write a parser for munging the current format to json, but I would like to do it 'the right way', and currently don't see where I'm going wrong..

Thanks for your time and your pointers.

```
....
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Request(db.Model):
    id: str = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    request_text: str = db.Column(db.String(400))   
    status: str = db.Column(db.String(400))   
    added_from: str = db.Column(db.String(400))  
    added_date: str = db.Column(db.String(400))      
    update_date: str = db.Column(db.String(400)) 


@socketio.on('getList')
def getList():
    requests = Request.query.all()
    print(requests)
```

and here is how the output currently looks:

```
[Request(id=1, request_text='Clown - Juggling balls in the air', status='Added', added_from='wish', added_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:10', update_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:10'), Request(id=2, request_text='a', status='Added', added_from='wish', added_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:12', update_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:12'), Request(id=3, request_text='b', status='Added', added_from='wish', added_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:13', update_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:13'), Request(id=4, request_text='c', status='Added', added_from='wish', added_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:14', update_date='11/18/2023, 16:06:14')]
```

Here's the ingredients of above results:

```
Python: 3.10.12
Flask: 2.2.5
Flask-Migrate: 4.0.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy: 3.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73146095/1874025), setting the class up like this and adding the "to_dict" at the bottom:

```
@dataclass
class Request(db.Model):
    id: str = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    request_text: str = db.Column(db.String(400))    
    status: str = db.Column(db.String(400))   
    added_from: str = db.Column(db.String(400))  
    added_date: str = db.Column(db.String(400))      
    update_date: str = db.Column(db.String(400)) 
    def to_dict(self):
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c}
```

and then querying it like this and creating my own dict-list:

```
def get_list():
    requests = Request.query.all()
    request_list = {}
    for request in requests:
        request_dict = request.to_dict()
        id = request_dict['id']
        request_list[id] = request_dict

    print(request_list)
```

or the same a bit more concise:

```
def get_list():
    requests = Request.query.all()
    request_list = dict((x.id, x.to_dict()) for x in requests)
    print(request_list)
```

Maybe this "repackaging" approach is not the most elegant solution, but it works for me. If anybody has a better approach, I'd be happy to learn about it. I feel this one is "hacky", in my absence of ability to figure out the "right way of doing it"

Update: I ended up using the proposal from snakecharmerb, and added filtration possibiltiy:

```
from dataclasses import asdict

def get_list(statuses = []):
    res= Request.query.filter(Request.status.in_(statuses) if statuses else True).all()
    request_list = [asdict(x) for x in res]
    print(request_list)
```

Comment: You could consider using [dataclasses.asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) instead of the `to_dict` method, at least for simple models with no relationships that you want to serialise. For more complex requirements consider marshmallow or pydantic, or roll your own `to_dict` methods.

Comment: thank you, @snakecharmerb. For my needs I think I'm going to use the version I have posted, since I can then refer to the respective items by id. Thanks much for showing me this method though, I did not know it.

Comment: For full transparency, I ended up using your approach ;-) Thanks again, @snakecharmerb. Updated the solution.