# Is there a way to remove the primary key from the SQLAlchemy query results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am working on a application with FastAPI, Pydantic and SQLAlchemy.

I want to return data matching a Pydantic scheme like

```
class UserResponseBody(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
```

The database model looks like

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    age = Column(Integer)
```

When I query the users in CRUD the records also contain the primary_key `id`,
which I don't want to expose to the user.

So far I am converting the query results to a dict and pop the primary key like

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350445/7919597
def object_as_dict(obj):
    return {c.key: getattr(obj, c.key)
            for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs}

query_result = db.query(models.User).first()

query_result_dict = object_as_dict(obj)
query_result_dict.pop("id", None)

return UserResponseBody(**query_result_dict)
```

But that feels kind of hacky and I would like to ask, if someone knows a better solution to this.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but `for c in inspect(obj).mapper.column_attrs if c.key != 'id'` seems like it would work.

Comment: I don't understand the problem here.  `UserResponseBody(**{'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice', 'age': 42}).json` -> `'{"name": "Alice", "age": 42}'`.  `id` is not present in the Pydantic model or its serialised output.

Comment: You can have a separate output model without that field. See the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have your response model defined, you just need to tell FastAPI that you want to use it, and that Pydantic should attempt to use `.property`-notation to resolve values as well:

```py
class UserResponseBody(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


@app.get('/users/first', response_model=UserResponseBody)
def get_first_user():
    return db.query(models.User).first()
```

Only the fields defined in your `response_model` will be included, which doesn't include `id` in your case. No need to do the conversion manually, FastAPI and Pydantic does what you want as long as you've told them what you want.

Comment: Is there a way to unittest models to see that this behavior works? Like take the schema and the db model and check if the `response_model` triggers a `ValidationError`?

Comment: What kind of validation error are you looking for? i.e. what is the case you want to test? You can use `TestClient` to make requests to the endpoint that you can test and have requests that fail/etc. depending on what you're giving as information (i.e. do it with an empty database and get `None` back, which hasn't been indicated as a valid response here - you'd probably do that by wrapping `UserResponseBody` in `Optional`).

Comment: I would like to have tests without the actual endpoints and TestClients, just with instances of schemas and model. So far I have to spin up the complete app to test this and this is a bit tedious. I would like to have a function like `convert_object_to_response_model(obj, response_model)` which would maybe throw an `ValidationError` if the conversion does not work.

Comment: You can use `UserResponseBody.from_orm(...)` on the model class directly to attempt to load an ORM result object, or you can use `parse_obj` or `parse_obj_as` from the Pydantic helper functions (availble directly under `pydantic`).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an MCVE at the moment, but I get a `ValidationError extra fields not permitted` when there is `extra = Extra.forbid` set in `UserResponseBody` and it is used as `response_model=UserResponseBody`. The extra field is the primary key of the database and I would have expected for it to be dropped if it is not used in the `response_model`. Could you maye shed some light on this? The object used to initialize it is the database query.

Comment: Does the dropping of fields in the `response_model` only work with `extra = Extra.ignore`?

Comment: If you explicitly tell Pydantic that fields that aren't converted are forbidden, yes, that will be an error. That's the point of saying `extra.forbid` - that if there are extra fields outside of those defined, that's an error. If you want extra fields to be ignored, leave it at its default (`Extra.ignore`). If you're telling Pydantic that additional fields to those that you've defined aren't allowed, it shouldn't come as a surprise that Pydantic raises an error if that occurs.