# How I can parse response with SQLAlchemy from multiple rows & columns to one field with list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My current output looks like:

| item | attribute_id | attribute_value | attribute_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | zone | A | zone_position |
| A | type | simple | type_item |
| A | status | active | state |

Desired output is:

| item | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| A | [{"attribute_id": "zone", "attribute_value": "A", "attribute_name": "zone_position"}, {"attribute_id: "type", "attribute_value": "simple", "attribute_name": "type_item"}, {"attribute_id": "status", "attribute_value": "active", "attribute_name": "state}] |

If that would be hard to be done from sql alchemy, How can be done from a json format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert SQLAlchemy row object to a Python dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/how-to-convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-a-python-dict)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958228/5320906) is the current best way to convert rows to dicts.

Comment: I feel like I am close, but still can't figure out how i can get the desired structure of my data

Comment: I think i would do it after the sqlalchemy result. Like if i would have the dictionary mapping ("item":"A", "attribute_id":"zone", "attribute_value":"A", "attribute_name":"zone_pozition"}, I would want to turn it into {"item" : "A", attributes: [{"attribute_id": "zone", "attribute_value": "A", "attribute_name": "zone_position"}].

Comment: @snakecharmerb used that ``` for row in result:
 row_as_dict = dict(row)
 row_as_dict["attributes"] = [{key: value for key, value in row_as_dict.items() if key in ["attribute_id", "attribute_value", "attribute_name"]}]
 print(row_as_dict) ``` and helped me a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.  We can use itertools.groupby to group results by the value of `item`, and tools from the operator module to abstract finding and extracting values.

```py
import itertools
import operator
import pprint

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

Base = orm.declarative_base()

# Assuming this model strcuture
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't74781694'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    item = sa.Column(sa.String)
    attribute_id = sa.Column(sa.String)
    attribute_value = sa.Column(sa.String)
    attribute_name = sa.Column(sa.String)


engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True, future=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine, future=True)

# The attributes that we want to group.
keys = ['attribute_id', 'attribute_value', 'attribute_name']

# ORM solution (using model entities).
attrgetter = operator.attrgetter(*keys)

with Session() as s:
    instances = s.scalars(sa.select(MyModel))
    data = [
        (k, [dict.fromkeys(keys, attrgetter(g)) for g in grouped])
        for k, grouped in itertools.groupby(instances, key=lambda m: m.item)
    ]
    pprint.pprint(data)

# Hybrid core/ORM solution (Using session and table).
# Pure core would entail using engine instead of session 
keygetter = operator.itemgetter('item')
itemgetter = operator.itemgetter(*keys)
with Session() as s:
    tbl = MyModel.__table__
    rows = s.execute(sa.select(tbl)).mappings()
    data = [
        (k, [dict.fromkeys(keys, itemgetter(g)) for g in grouped])
        for k, grouped in itertools.groupby(rows, key=keygetter)
    ]
    pprint.pprint(data)
```