# Returning a json response when using flask_sqlalchemy and autoload_with

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a python program to connect to an existing SQLITE database and provide a JSON endpoint to access the contents of a table. But I can't seem to figure out how to convert the Rows returned from a query into a JSON serializable format.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///some-path\\db.sqlite'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()
db.reflect()

Images = db.Table(
         "images", 
         db.Model.metadata,
         autoload_with=db.engine
    )

@app.route("/all")
def alldata():
    alldata =db.session.query(Images).all()
    results = [tuple(row) for row in alldata]
    return json.loads(json.dumps(results))
```

The above code works but loses all the column names (plus it feels extremely messy).

All of the solutions I have found recommend adding some sort of serialization function to my `Images` class ... but the problem with that is I have not created a class to represent my tables structure (instead, I'm using `autoload_with`).

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to do this? Am I using `autoload_with` incorrectly?

## UPDATE 1:

I have tried the following:

```
@app.route("/all")
def alldata():
    return db.session.execute(db.select(Images)).mappings()
```

Unfortunately, this results in `AssertionError: applications must write bytes`

## UPDATE 2

This: `return db.session.execute(db.select(Images)).mappings().all()` gives the following error:
`Object of type RowMapping is not JSON serializable`

## UPDATE 3

This is the code I used to create the original images table with `sqlalchemy`:

```
images = Table(
   'images', meta, 
   Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True), 
   Column('url', String),
   Column('meta', String)
)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311205/5320906) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958228/5320906) answer your question? (so you would do `db.execute(db.select(Images)).mappings()`).

Comment: ```AttributeError: execute``` ... I guess this doesn't work in the latest version of flask_sqlalchemy

Comment: My bad, `db.session.execute`

Comment: This gave ```AssertionError: applications must write bytes```. I tried wrapping it in ```json.dumps()``` but just got ```Object of type MappingResult is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Can you share the definition of the images table from the database please?

Comment: I have added it as an update to the question above. Thanks!