I want to update a data in mysql table using python , flask , rest api but it doesn't work when I use postman
I created a table in flask_sqlalchemy
class Cafe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    map_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    seats = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    has_toilet = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_wifi = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_sockets = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    can_take_calls = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    coffee_price = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        #Method 1. 
        dictionary = {}
        # Loop through each column in the data record
        for column in self.__table__.columns:
            #Create a new dictionary entry;
            # where the key is the name of the column
            # and the value is the value of the column
            dictionary[column.name] = getattr(self, column.name)
        return dictionary

and I have created rest API for this to add more cafe datas.
using this code
@app.route("/add",methods=["POST"])
def add_cafe():
    body = request.form
    try:
        new_cafe = Cafe(
            name=request.form['name'],
            location=request.form['location'],
            seats=request.form['seats'],
            img_url=request.form['img_url'],
            map_url=request.form['map_url'],
            coffee_price=request.form['coffee_price'],
            has_wifi=bool(request.form['has_wifi']),
            has_toilet=bool(request.form['has_toilet']),
            has_sockets=bool(request.form['has_sockets']),
            can_take_calls=bool(request.form['can_take_calls']),
        )
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify(error={"Bad Request": "Some or all fields were incorrect or missing."})
    else:
        with app.app_context():
            db.session.add(new_cafe)
            db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(response={"success": f"Successfully added the new cafe."})

thankfully, this two block of codes works fine. but the issue is in this code
@app.route("/update-price/<int:cafe_id>",methods=["PATCH"])
def patch_new_cafe():
    new_price = request.args.get("new_price")
    cafe = db.session.query(Cafe).get("cafe_id")
    cafe.coffee.price = new_price
    if cafe:
        with app.app_context():
            db.session.commit()
        return jsonify(response={"Success":"Successfully updated the price"}),200
    else:
        return jsonify(response={"Not Found":"Sorry a cafe with that id was not found in the database."}),404

so suppose I want to change the price of coffee in a cafe which got an ID of 4 to $5 it works and this is the response
{
"response": {
"success": "Successfully updated the price."
}
}
and it works fine. The data changed in mysql table when I checked using db browser
but when I literally copy pasted the same code with a tiny change to the price in postman PATCH. This is what I got -_- . Most likely I made a dumb mistake or something but please forgive me I am new in creating api I've spent an entire day for this.
this is the error.

You don't need to write your own to_dict() method. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/how-to-convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-a-python-dict

I think it should be def patch_new_cafe(cafe_id):. You're missing the parameter.

You should take a look at using Variable Rules and use the resulting id in the query for the database.

Yall. I found the solution . Apparently I had two functions of name patch_new_cafe() one with parameter and other one with not. So the python read the first function which is the one without the parameter and gave the error. Like I said I made a dumb mistake which means I need to sleep. Thank you Barmar your solution fixed it and thank you for the to_dict() method tip. Also thanks to Detlef for helping.
